# Find the min/max element of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I easily obtain the min or max element of a JavaScript array?

Example pseudocode:

```
let array = [100, 0, 50]

array.min() //=> 0
array.max() //=> 100
```

Comment: **Note:** With ECMAScript 6 you can use the new [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (three dots: `...`) with `Math.max()` like this: `Math.max(...[2, 5, 16, 1])`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30834687) made from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Examples).

Comment: here a benchmark for a speed comparison of the most common ways to do it: http://jsben.ch/#/1QuTg

Comment: **Without ES6** `Math.max.apply(null, [2,5,16,1])`

Comment: In ES6, obtaining both the maximum and minimum can be [done with only one `reduce` call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63514134/9513184).

Comment: @totymedli 's solution of using the spread operator is not a good idea. If the array is too large, this will cause a stack overflow exception (too many parameters being passed to the function).
A much better idea is ot use `reduce`

Comment: @AronFiechter Did you actually read my answer? I explain all the options in great detail with code examples and benchmarks. The call stack size is only a problem if your arrays have a size larger than 100000. While the call stack has to be considered, in most cases it won't be an issue and the more concise code outweighs the drawbacks.

Comment: This call stack may be an issue. There's a HackerRank question that requires finding min and max, and the tests run under a limit of 10 seconds. The arrays passed in by HackerRank for the 9th to 14th tests have lengths of >100,000; and will fail if the reduce solution in the answer below is used. The for-loop will pass for some

Comment: Use ```...```(spread operator): ```const maxValue = Math.max(...array))```

Answer (score 1091):

How about augmenting the built-in Array object to use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)/[`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) instead:

```js
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};

let p = [35,2,65,7,8,9,12,121,33,99];

console.log(`Max value is: ${p.max()}` +
  `\nMin value is: ${p.min()}`);
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilagarwal530/np9L66bv/)**.

Augmenting the built-ins can cause collisions with other libraries (some see), so you may be more comfortable with just `apply`'ing `Math.xxx()` to your array directly:

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr),
    max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
```

---

Alternately, assuming your browser supports ECMAScript 6, you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) which functions similarly to the `apply` method:

```
var min = Math.min( ...arr ),
    max = Math.max( ...arr );
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "return Math.max.apply( Math, this );" and not return Math.max.apply( null, this );

Comment: @HankH: maybe. `Math.max` is akin to a "static" method, so there is no useful `this` instance inside of it (I hope). So assuming that is true, calling it would run it in the global scope (i.e. `window`), which is equivalent to passing `null` as the first paramter to `apply`/`call`.

Comment: @HankH: passing `null` or `Math` or `{}` or whatever to `apply()` or `call()` has no bearing on the outcome. `Math.max` does not nor should not reference `this` internally.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: you are absolutely right. This does not work on any other type.

Comment: This is a great theoretical answer, but in practice has some flaws. Big arrays return different arrays for Node.js and Chrome. Better solutions for big arrays are presented below, not so fancy, but stronger than this one.

Comment: Just sharing a jQuery mistake I was making with the code above which took me a long time to debug. A jquery array works fine on everything but the iPad. I had to convert the array to a true native array for it to work. Only affected the single device for some reason `Math.max.apply(null, $.makeArray(array));`

Comment: @Forrest: what is a "jquery array"?

Comment: @RoatinMarth It's an "array-like object", like what is returned from finding DOM-elements with the jQuery selector. Read [jQuery's explanation of the makeArray function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/).

Comment: I've downvoted, because proposed approach consumes O(n) memory in stack frame, and as a result crashes on large arrays. In my case just about 130000 numbers were enough to crash nodejs.

Comment: Don't augment built-in prototypes like this. It's not just about conflicts with other libraries; it's also about the potential that the browser itself provides a `.max` or `.min` method in future. Perfectly realistic scenario: *You use this answer. In 2016, ES7 or ES8 spec `Array.max` and `Array.min`. Unlike this version, they work on strings. Your future colleague tries to get the alphabetically-latest string in an array with the now-well-documented native `.max()` method, but mysteriously gets `NaN`. Hours later, she finds this code, runs a `git blame`, and curses your name.*

Comment: ... or just wrap code `if (!Array.max) { ... } ` so that if browser ever does add these methods they don't get replaced.

Comment: Note that this has a length limit because all values are passed as arguments. I run some tests on my pc, `Math.max` could accept up to 100,000 arguments on Chrome, 300,000 on Firefox, 400,000 on Edge, 150,000 on IE11 (tested on Win10, all browsers latest).

Comment: This is a very slow method, what if array would have thousands of elements?

Comment: This also fails if any element is NaN, undefined, null or the array is sparse (i.e. not contiguous, e.g. `[,1,2].max()` returns *NaN*).

Comment: Why change the prototype of a primitive object when you can just create a function that accepts an array and doesn't have side effects on the entire environment in which your code operates?

Comment: To avoid `max` output in object keys, use syntax: ```
if (!Array.prototype['max']) {
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'max', {
        "value": function () {
            return Math.max.apply(null, this);
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false,
    });
}
``` 

Try: 
```
for (let i in a) {
    console.log(i, '->', a[i]);
}
```

Comment: `Better max` is `Object.values(a).reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b), -Infinity)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 461):

```
var max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, array);
```

For a full discussion see:
http://aaroncrane.co.uk/2008/11/javascript_max_api/

Comment: What is the difference between `Math.max.apply(Math, array)` and `Math.max.apply(null, array)`? The blog says "...you also have to redundantly say again that `max` belongs to `Math`...", but it seems I don't have to do so (by setting the first argument of `apply` as `null`).

Comment: @ziyuang When you call it like `Math.max(a,b)`, `Math` is passed as the `this` value, so it might make sense to do the same when calling with `apply`. But `Math.max` does not use the `this` value, so you can pass whatever value you want.

Answer (score 348):

Using spread operator (ES6)

```
Math.max(...array)  // The same with "min" => Math.min(...array)
```

```js
const array = [10, 2, 33, 4, 5];

console.log(
  Math.max(...array)
)
```

Comment: This solution was already provided by [multiple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30834687/1494454) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27537882/1494454) answers.

Comment: Math.max(...[]) = -Infinity.  hahaha 

Comment: @DavidPortabella not sure why that's funny. That's how it works [according to the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-math.max): `If no arguments are given, the result is -∞.`

Comment: yes, I meant that the javascript specification is horrible. It seems obvious that the min of no numbers cannot be computed. In other more serious programming languages, such as Scala, asking for the min of an empty array throws an exception.

Comment: This is a very slow method, what if array would have thousands of elements?

Comment: Doesn't work with array of Date strings. Use `dates.reduce(function (a, b) { return a > b ? a : b; });`

Comment: @totymedli : the differentiator in this answer is that one line .. no need to waste reader time :)

Comment: what would be the time complexity of this solution using the spread operator?

Comment: Not sure if the builtin Math.max function would be faster with infinity values. haha

Answer (score 292):

For big arrays (~10⁷ elements), `Math.min` and `Math.max` both produces the following error in Node.js.

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

A more robust solution is to not add every element to the call stack, but to instead pass an array:

```
function arrayMin(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (p, v) {
    return ( p < v ? p : v );
  });
}

function arrayMax(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (p, v) {
    return ( p > v ? p : v );
  });
}
```

If you are concerned about speed, the following code is ~3 times faster then `Math.max.apply` is on my computer. See https://jsben.ch/JPOyL.

```
function arrayMin(arr) {
  var len = arr.length, min = Infinity;
  while (len--) {
    if (arr[len] < min) {
      min = arr[len];
    }
  }
  return min;
};

function arrayMax(arr) {
  var len = arr.length, max = -Infinity;
  while (len--) {
    if (arr[len] > max) {
      max = arr[len];
    }
  }
  return max;
};
```

If your arrays contains strings instead of numbers, you also need to coerce them into numbers. The below code does that, but it slows the code down ~10 times on my machine. See https://jsben.ch/uPipD.

```
function arrayMin(arr) {
  var len = arr.length, min = Infinity;
  while (len--) {
    if (Number(arr[len]) < min) {
      min = Number(arr[len]);
    }
  }
  return min;
};

function arrayMax(arr) {
  var len = arr.length, max = -Infinity;
  while (len--) {
    if (Number(arr[len]) > max) {
      max = Number(arr[len]);
    }
  }
  return max;
};
```

Comment: assign `min` and `max` to last element and reduce the iterations by 1 (`while(--len)`) ;)

Comment: @Venugopal then you need a special check to see if the array is empty and return +/- Infinity

Comment: Strange... I went to the linked website... and testing in Firefox 51.0.0 / Mac OS X 10.12.0, the reduce-based approach is 30% slower than loop-based ... very different results

Comment: https://jsperf.com/array-min-max-random/1

starting from 60 elements Math methods are breaking equal with while cycles, if array size is greater than 60, than Math methods wins. Larger the array - greater the Math methods overtake. ( for 100 elems Math.min/max is 10% faster, for 1000 elems its +25%  )

Comment: Yes you should add a quick check and assign one element of the array to min and max, because just assign a very extreme value maybe fine for most applications, but it is not fully correct. A expected behavior would be: get the min or max (and nothing else) or an error/exception (e.g. if the array is empty). But just return +-inf would be wrong. (and an extra check after every usage have to be implemented.)

Comment: **In 2019** the `reduce` solution is the slowest. Even if you work with an array that has millions of elements, it is **better to use the standard for loop**. [See my answer for more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834687/1494454)

Answer (score 181):

### tl;dr

```js
// For regular arrays:
var max = Math.max(...arrayOfNumbers);

// For arrays with tens of thousands of items:
let max = testArray[0];
for (let i = 1; i < testArrayLength; ++i) {
  if (testArray[i] > max) {
    max = testArray[i];
  }
}
```

### MDN solution

The [official MDN docs on `Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Examples) already covers this issue:

> The following function uses [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to find the maximum element in a numeric array. `getMaxOfArray([1, 2, 3])` is equivalent to `Math.max(1, 2, 3)`, but you can use `getMaxOfArray()` on programmatically constructed arrays of any size.
>
> ```
> function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
>     return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
> }
> ```
>
> Or with the new [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), getting the maximum of an array becomes a lot easier.
>
> ```
> var arr = [1, 2, 3];
> var max = Math.max(...arr);
> ```

### Maximum size of an array

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions) the `apply` and spread solutions *had* a limitation of 65536 that came from the limit of the maximum number of arguments:

> But beware: in using apply this way, you run the risk of exceeding the JavaScript engine's argument length limit. The consequences of applying a function with too many arguments (think more than tens of thousands of arguments) vary across engines (**JavaScriptCore has hard-coded argument limit of 65536**), because the limit (indeed even the nature of any excessively-large-stack behavior) is unspecified. Some engines will throw an exception. More perniciously, others will arbitrarily limit the number of arguments actually passed to the applied function. To illustrate this latter case: if such an engine had a limit of four arguments (actual limits are of course significantly higher), it would be as if the arguments 5, 6, 2, 3 had been passed to apply in the examples above, rather than the full array.

They even provide a hybrid solution which doesn't really have good performance compared to other solutions. See performance test below for more.

In 2019 the **actual limit is the maximum size of the call stack**. For modern Chromium based desktop browsers this means that when it comes to finding min/max with `apply` or spread, **practically the maximum size for numbers only arrays is ~120000**. Above this, there will be a stack overflow and the following error will be thrown:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

With the script below (based on [this blog post](http://2ality.com/2014/04/call-stack-size.html)), by catching that error you can calculate the limit for your specific environment.

**Warning!** Running this script takes time and depending on the performance of your system it might slow or crash your browser/system!

```js
let testArray = Array.from({length: 10000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000000));
for (i = 10000; i < 1000000; ++i) {
  testArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000000));
  try {
    Math.max.apply(null, testArray);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(i);
    break;
  }
}
```

### Performance on large arrays

Based on the test in [EscapeNetscape](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689455/escapenetscape)'s comment I created some benchmarks that tests 5 different methods on a **random number only array with 100000 items**.

In 2019, the results show that the **standard loop** (which BTW doesn't have the size limitation) is the fastest everywhere. **`apply` and spread** comes closely after it, then much later MDN's hybrid solution then `reduce` as the slowest.

Almost all tests gave the same results, except for one where spread somewhy ended up being the slowest.

If you step up your array to have 1 million items, things start to break and you are left with the standard loop as a fast solution and `reduce` as a slower.

#### [JSPerf benchmark](https://jsperf.com/find-min-max-of-array)

[image: jsperf.com benchmark results for different solutions to find the min/max item of an array]

#### [JSBen benchmark](http://jsben.ch/dZHfx)

[image: jsben.com benchmark results for different solutions to find the min/max item of an array]

#### [JSBench.me benchmark](http://jsbench.me)

[image: jsbench.me benchmark results for different solutions to find the min/max item of an array]

#### Benchmark source code

```js
var testArrayLength = 100000
var testArray = Array.from({length: testArrayLength}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000000));

// ES6 spread
Math.min(...testArray);
Math.max(...testArray);

// reduce
testArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.max(a, b);
});
testArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.min(a, b);
});

// apply
Math.min.apply(Math, testArray);
Math.max.apply(Math, testArray);

// standard loop
let max = testArray[0];
for (let i = 1; i < testArrayLength; ++i) {
  if (testArray[i] > max) {
    max = testArray[i];
  }
}

let min = testArray[0];
for (let i = 1; i < testArrayLength; ++i) {
  if (testArray[i] < min) {
    min = testArray[i];
  }
}

// MDN hibrid soltuion
// Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions
function minOfArray(arr) {
  var min = Infinity;
  var QUANTUM = 32768;

  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += QUANTUM) {
    var submin = Math.min.apply(null, arr.slice(i, Math.min(i + QUANTUM, len)));
    min = Math.min(submin, min);
  }

  return min;
}

minOfArray(testArray);

function maxOfArray(arr) {
  var max = -Infinity;
  var QUANTUM = 32768;

  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += QUANTUM) {
    var submax = Math.max.apply(null, arr.slice(i, Math.max(i + QUANTUM, len)));
    max = Math.max(submax, max);
  }

  return max;
}

maxOfArray(testArray);
```

Comment: If you're using typescript the spread operator as shown is compiled to `Math.max.apply(Math, arr)` for 'max' compatibility.

Comment: Also from MDN: 
"both spread `(...)` and `apply` will either fail or return the wrong result if the array has too many elements [...] The reduce solution does not have this problem"
Testing Chrome, FF, Edge and IE11 it seems that it is ok for an array of up to 100k values.
(Tested on Win10 and latest browsers: Chrome 110k, Firefox 300k, Edge 400k, IE11 150k).

Comment: This is a very slow method, what if array would have thousands of elements?

Comment: @SlavaFominII I extended the answer so it covers arrays with thousands of elements.

Answer (score 74):

If you're paranoid like me about using `Math.max.apply` (which could cause errors when given large arrays [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions)), try this:

```
function arrayMax(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  });
}

function arrayMin(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.min(a, b);
  });
}
```

Or, in ES6:

```
function arrayMax(array) {
  return array.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b));
}

function arrayMin(array) {
  return array.reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b));
}
```

The anonymous functions are unfortunately necessary (instead of using `Math.max.bind(Math)` because `reduce` doesn't just pass `a` and `b` to its function, but also `i` and a reference to the array itself, so we have to ensure we don't try to call `max` on those as well.

Comment: Your ES6 example, is there any reason why not just return `Math.max(...array)`?

Comment: @WojciechBednarski [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_apply) seems to suggest that using the spread operator is the same as passing an array to `apply`, and therefore has the same downsides (maximum argument limit).

Comment: Thanks for this. Just you can correct missing bracket after reduce: `function arrayMax(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  }); // <--------- missing )
}`

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster you can simplify it like this: `array.reduce(Math.min)`. Additionally I would add an initial value for the cases that the array length is 0 or 1: `array.reduce(Math.min, defaultValue)`.

Comment: **Update:** Sorry, I just recognized that Math.min takes a variable amount of arguments. My suggestion above does **not** work.

Comment: @DanielDietrich I guess doing the equivalent, calling `Math.min()` with no values, returns `Infinity`, so these functions could use `reduce(..., Infinity)` to match that behaviour. I prefer it to throw an exception though (as it does currently), because taking the minimum of an empty array seems likely to be an error.

Comment: so far reduce is the slowest.

Answer (score 63):

## Min/Max Alternative Methods

---

###### The [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) are great methods to get the minimum and maximum items out of a collection of items. However, it's important to be aware of some cavities that can come with it.

Using them with an array containing a large number of items *(more than ~10⁷ items, depending on the user's browser)* most likely will ***crash*** and give the following error message:

```
const arr = Array.from(Array(1000000).keys());
Math.min(arr);
Math.max(arr);
```

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

---

**Some browsers** might return a `NaN` value instead. It might be a better way to handle errors, but it doesn't solve the problem just yet.

Instead, for very large numbers, consider using something like this:

```js
function maxValue(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((max, val) => max > val ? max : val)
}
const arr = Array.from(Array(1000000).keys());
console.log(maxValue(arr)); // 999999
```

**Better** run-time:

```js
function maxValue(arr) {
  let max = arr[0];

  for (let val of arr) {
    if (val > max) {
      max = val;
    }
  }
  return max;
}
const arr = Array.from(Array(1000000).keys());
console.log(maxValue(arr)); // 999999
```

---

Get both Min and Max:

```js
function getMinMax(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(({min, max}, v) => ({
    min: min < v ? min : v,
    max: max > v ? max : v,
  }), { min: arr[0], max: arr[0] });
}
const arr = Array.from(Array(1000000).keys());
console.log(getMinMax(arr)); // {"min":0,"max":999999}
```

**Better** run-time*:

```js
function getMinMax(arr) {
  let min = arr[0];
  let max = arr[0];
  let i = arr.length;
    
  while (i--) {
    min = arr[i] < min ? arr[i] : min;
    max = arr[i] > max ? arr[i] : max;
  }
  return { min, max };
}
const arr = Array.from(Array(1000000).keys());
console.log(getMinMax(arr)); // {"min":0,"max":999999}
```

* Tested with 1,000,000 items:
Just for reference, the 1st function run-time (on my machine) was 15.84ms vs. 2nd function with only 4.32ms.

Comment: Just spread the array. `Math.min(...arr)`.

Comment: @RicardoNolde Unfortunately spreading the array doesn't change the way that the Math.min/max functions works  (Tested on Chrome v91). If that works for you, please share which browser/version you use.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The `NaN` problem happens because you're passing a straight array. In the browsers I have tested, it always returns `NaN`; that can be solved by spreading the array. The other issue you've raised -- the maximum call stack size -- still applies, regardless of spread.

Answer (score 45):

Two ways are shorter and easy:

```
let arr = [2, 6, 1, 0]
```

**Way 1**:

```
let max = Math.max.apply(null, arr)
```

**Way 2**:

```
let max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
});
```

Comment: Watch out if the array is empty - you'll get negative infinity which may not be what you want. If you prefer to get `0` you can use `[0].concat(arr)` or with spread syntax `[0, ...arr]` (in place of 'arr')

Comment: is there a way to exclude null values in Way 1?

Comment: @hafizur-rahman way #1 cannot deal with large numbers! (as #2 can). Try with any array that has more than ~10⁷ items - Array.from(Array(1000000).keys())

Answer (score 42):

`.apply` is often used when the intention is to invoke a variadic function with a list of argument values, e.g.

The [`Math.max([value1[,value2, ...]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function returns the largest of zero or more numbers.

```
Math.max(10, 20); // 20
Math.max(-10, -20); // -10
Math.max(-10, 20); // 20
```

The `Math.max()` method doesn't allow you to pass in an array. If you have a list of values of which you need to get the largest, you would normally call this function using [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), e.g.

```
Math.max.apply(null, [10, 20]); // 20
Math.max.apply(null, [-10, -20]); // -10
Math.max.apply(null, [-10, 20]); // 20
```

However, as of the **ECMAScript 6** you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

> The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) are expected.

Using the spread operator, the above can be rewritten as such:

```
Math.max(...[10, 20]); // 20
Math.max(...[-10, -20]); // -10
Math.max(...[-10, 20]); // 20
```

When calling a function using the variadic operator, you can even add additional values, e.g.

```
Math.max(...[10, 20], 50); // 50
Math.max(...[-10, -20], 50); // 50
```

**Bonus:**

Spread operator enables you to use the array literal syntax to create new arrays in situations where in ES5 you would need to fall back to imperative code, using a combination of `push`, `splice`, etc.

```
let foo = ['b', 'c'];
let bar = ['a', ...foo, 'd', 'e']; // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Your last example in the bonus would be written using `concat` by most programers because it let you maintain a single line style.

Answer (score 24):

You do it by extending the Array type:

```
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};
Array.min = function( array ){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};
```

Boosted from [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/) (by John Resig)

Answer (score 22):

A simple solution to find the minimum value over an `Array` of elements is to use the `Array` prototype function `reduce`:

```
A = [4,3,-9,-2,2,1];
A.reduce((min, val) => val < min ? val : min, A[0]); // returns -9
```

or using JavaScript's built-in Math.Min() function (thanks @Tenflex):

```
A.reduce((min,val) => Math.min(min,val), A[0]);
```

This sets `min` to `A[0]`, and then checks for `A[1]...A[n]` whether it is strictly less than the current `min`. If `A[i] < min` then `min` is updated to `A[i]`. When all array elements has been processed, `min` is returned as the result.

**EDIT**: Include position of minimum value:

```
A = [4,3,-9,-2,2,1];
A.reduce((min, val) => val < min._min ? {_min: val, _idx: min._curr, _curr: min._curr + 1} : {_min: min._min, _idx: min._idx, _curr: min._curr + 1}, {_min: A[0], _idx: 0, _curr: 0}); // returns { _min: -9, _idx: 2, _curr: 6 }
```

Comment: A.reduce((min,val) => Math.min(min,val),A[0]); even shorter

Comment: As a bonus question, how to have not only `min` value returned but also its position in the Array?

Answer (score 18):

For a concise, modern solution, one can perform a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation over the array, keeping track of the current minimum and maximum values, so the array is only iterated over once (which is optimal). [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is used here for succinctness.

```js
let array = [100, 0, 50];
let [min, max] = array.reduce(([prevMin,prevMax], curr)=>
   [Math.min(prevMin, curr), Math.max(prevMax, curr)], [Infinity, -Infinity]);
console.log("Min:", min);
console.log("Max:", max);
```

To only find either the minimum or maximum, we can use perform a reduce operation in much the same way, but we only need to keep track of the previous optimal value. This method is better than using `apply` as it will not cause errors when the array is too large for the stack.

```js
const arr = [-1, 9, 3, -6, 35];

//Only find minimum
const min = arr.reduce((a,b)=>Math.min(a,b), Infinity);
console.log("Min:", min);//-6

//Only find maximum
const max = arr.reduce((a,b)=>Math.max(a,b), -Infinity);
console.log("Max:", max);//35
```

Answer (score 16):

Others have already given some solutions in which they augment `Array.prototype`. All I want in this answer is to clarify whether it should be `Math.min.apply( Math, array )` or `Math.min.apply( null, array )`. **So what context should be used, `Math` or `null`?**

When passing `null` as a context to `apply`, then the context will default to the global object (the `window` object in the case of browsers). Passing the `Math` object as the context would be the correct solution, but it won't hurt passing `null` either. Here's an example when `null` might cause trouble, when decorating the `Math.max` function:

```
// decorate Math.max
(function (oldMax) {
    Math.max = function () {
        this.foo(); // call Math.foo, or at least that's what we want

        return oldMax.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(Math.max);

Math.foo = function () {
    print("foo");
};

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this); // <-- passing null as the context
};

var max = [1, 2, 3].max();

print(max);
```

The above will throw an exception because `this.foo` will be evaluated as `window.foo`, which is `undefined`. If we replace `null` with `Math`, things will work as expected and the string "foo" will be printed to the screen (I tested this using [Mozilla Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)).

You can pretty much assume that nobody has decorated `Math.max` so, passing `null` will work without problems.

Comment: Point taken. However why would someone decorate `Foo.staticMethod` and  reference `this`? Would that not be a mistake in the design of the decorator? (unless of course they were *wanting* to reference the global scope, and *want* to remain independent of the JavaScript engine being used, eg Rhino).

Comment: [The spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) is explicit about which specced functions should refer to "the **this** value" (indeed, that phrase appears 125 times in the specification). `Math.max`, implemented per spec, does not use `this`. If somebody overrides `Math.max` such that it does use `this`, then they have made its behaviour violate spec and you should throw sharp objects at them. You should not code around that possibility any more than you would code around the possibility that somebody has swapped `Math.max` and `Math.min` for the lulz.

Answer (score 16):

One more way to do it:

```
var arrayMax = Function.prototype.apply.bind(Math.max, null);
```

Usage:

```
var max = arrayMax([2, 5, 1]);
```

Comment: Can someone explain how this works? This is pretty dope. Is my understanding correct: arrayMax is a function and we bind something to a property of its prototype? What is this apply.bind and does every prototype have it?

Comment: You may check out:  http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/

Answer (score 15):

I am surprised not one mentiond the reduce function.

```
var arr = [1, 10, 5, 11, 2]

var b = arr.reduce(function(previous,current){ 
                      return previous > current ? previous:current
                   });

b => 11
arr => [1, 10, 5, 11, 2]
```

Comment: Be aware: reduce() is supported from IE9, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: I can't seem to use this in the current version of Chromium.

Answer (score 14):

This may suit your purposes.

```
Array.prototype.min = function(comparer) {

    if (this.length === 0) return null;
    if (this.length === 1) return this[0];

    comparer = (comparer || Math.min);

    var v = this[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
        v = comparer(this[i], v);    
    }

    return v;
}

Array.prototype.max = function(comparer) {

    if (this.length === 0) return null;
    if (this.length === 1) return this[0];

    comparer = (comparer || Math.max);

    var v = this[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
        v = comparer(this[i], v);    
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: you should initialize your v with 'this[0]' in case no numbers are smaller than 0

Comment: Is `comparer` supposed to be called in some specific scope? Because as is it references `this[index]` which is `undefined` everytime.

Comment: Fixed, I always forget about function level scoping.

Comment: Oh now, now @Ionut G. Stan will critique you for the same "wrong context" argument as he did me, since your default comparer (`Math.xxx`) will be running in the global scope...

Comment: That may be true, but the new function signature requires no scope as it takes the 2 objects that needs to be compared.

Answer (score 14):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

```js
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}

var arr = [100, 0, 50];
console.log(getMaxOfArray(arr))
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

I thought I'd share my simple and easy to understand solution.

For the min:

```js
var arr = [3, 4, 12, 1, 0, 5];
var min = arr[0];
for (var k = 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
  if (arr[k] < min) {
    min = arr[k];
  }
}
console.log("Min is: " + min);
```

And for the max:

```js
var arr = [3, 4, 12, 1, 0, 5];
var max = arr[0];
for (var k = 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
  if (arr[k] > max) {
    max = arr[k];
  }
}
console.log("Max is: " + max);
```

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: Thanks. I changed my answer.

Comment: The iteration is still wrong (accessing non-existing properties).

Comment: What is wrong, I don't see anything wrong. Can you offer an example please?

Comment: You need `k < arr.length` not `<=`. And you probably will want to start from index `k = 1` if you already took `arr[0]` as the initial value (which, btw, is wrong in your `max` calculation as well)

Comment: Modified accordingly now. Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: hi @lonut , i have a requirement similar to this, ie i need highest five values in that array instead of only one max value. can you help me to sought out this!.

Comment: Hi @SukumarDhoni, please post a new question and give me the link.

Comment: thanks for reply here is the link [clickhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237180/how-to-get-the-max-five-values-from-an-array-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 12):

let array = [267, 306, 108]
let longest = Math.max(...array);

Comment: This exact approach has already been mentioned in [totymedli’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834687/4642212), [C.K’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066646/4642212), [Abdennour TOUMI’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106546/4642212), [shilovk’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37300098/4642212), not including all the deleted answers. Your (unformatted) answer adds nothing.

Answer (score 10):

For big arrays (~10⁷ elements), `Math.min` and `Math.max` procuces a RangeError (Maximum call stack size exceeded) in node.js.

For big arrays, a quick & dirty solution is:

```
Array.prototype.min = function() {
    var r = this[0];
    this.forEach(function(v,i,a){if (v<r) r=v;});
    return r;
};
```

Answer (score 10):

Aside using the math function max and min, another function to use is the built in function of sort(): here we go

```
const nums = [12, 67, 58, 30].sort((x, y) => 
x -  y)
let min_val = nums[0]
let max_val = nums[nums.length -1]
```

Comment: Hmm wouldn't `sort()` take O(n*log(n)) time whereas merely iterating through the array would take linear time?

Answer (score 10):

```
array.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];
```

Gives you the maximum value in an array of numbers.

```
array.sort((a, b) => a - b)[0];
```

Gives you the minimum value in an array of numbers.

```js
let array = [0,20,45,85,41,5,7,85,90,111];

let maximum = array.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];
let minimum = array.sort((a, b) => a - b)[0];

console.log(minimum, maximum)
```

Answer (score 10):

For an array containing objects instead of numbers:

```
arr = [
  { name: 'a', value: 5 },
  { name: 'b', value: 3 },
  { name: 'c', value: 4 }
]
```

You can use `reduce` to get the element with the smallest value (min)

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a.value < b.value ? a : b)
// { name: 'b', value: 3 }
```

or the largest value (max)

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a.value > b.value ? a : b)
// { name: 'a', value: 5 }
```

Answer (score 10):

The best way with `Math.min(...array)` and `Math.max(...array)`

Answer (score 9):

Iterate through, keeping track as you go.

```
var min = null;
var max = null;
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i)
{
    var elem = arr[i];
    if (min === null || min > elem) min = elem;
    if (max === null || max < elem) max = elem;
}
alert( "min = " + min + ", max = " + max );
```

This will leave min/max null if there are no elements in the array.  Will set min and max in one pass if the array has any elements.

You could also extend Array with a `range` method using the above to allow reuse and improve on readability.  See a working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/9C9fU/

```
Array.prototype.range = function() {

    var min = null,
        max = null,
        i, len;

    for (i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i)
    {
        var elem = this[i];
        if (min === null || min > elem) min = elem;
        if (max === null || max < elem) max = elem;
    }

    return { min: min, max: max }
};
```

Used as

```
var arr = [3, 9, 22, -7, 44, 18, 7, 9, 15];

var range = arr.range();

console.log(range.min);
console.log(range.max);
```

Comment: @JordanDillonChapian I'd agree, but it would be trivial to extend this to a `range` function that would be the best way to get both the min and max at the same time IMO - as I've done with an update to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, I needed to obtain the minimum and maximum values of an array and, to my surprise, there were no built-in functions for arrays. After reading a lot, I decided to test the "top 3" solutions myself:

1. discrete solution: a FOR loop to check every element of the array against the current max and/or min value;
2. APPLY solution: sending the array to the Math.max and/or Math.min internal functions using apply(null,array);
3. REDUCE solution: recursing a check against every element of the array using reduce(function).

The test code was this:

```
function GetMaxDISCRETE(A)
{   var MaxX=A[0];

    for (var X=0;X<A.length;X++)
        if (MaxX<A[X])
            MaxX=A[X];

    return MaxX;
}

function GetMaxAPPLY(A)
{   return Math.max.apply(null,A);
}

function GetMaxREDUCE(A)
{   return A.reduce(function(p,c)
    {   return p>c?p:c;
    });
}
```

The array A was filled with 100,000 random integer numbers, each function was executed 10,000 times on Mozilla Firefox 28.0 on an intel Pentium 4 2.99GHz desktop with Windows Vista. The times are in seconds, retrieved by performance.now() function. The results were these, with 3 fractional digits and standard deviation:

1. Discrete solution: mean=0.161s, sd=0.078
2. APPLY solution: mean=3.571s, sd=0.487
3. REDUCE solution: mean=0.350s, sd=0.044

The REDUCE solution was 117% slower than the discrete solution. The APPLY solution was the worse, 2,118% slower than the discrete solution. Besides, as Peter observed, it doesn't work for large arrays (about more than 1,000,000 elements).

Also, to complete the tests, I tested this extended discrete code:

```
var MaxX=A[0],MinX=A[0];

for (var X=0;X<A.length;X++)
{   if (MaxX<A[X])
        MaxX=A[X];
    if (MinX>A[X])
        MinX=A[X];
}
```

The timing: mean=0.218s, sd=0.094

So, it is 35% slower than the simple discrete solution, but it retrieves both the maximum and the minimum values at once (any other solution would take at least twice that to retrieve them). Once the OP needed both values, the discrete solution would be the best choice (even as two separate functions, one for calculating maximum and another for calculating minimum, they would outperform the second best, the REDUCE solution).

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following function anywhere in your project:

```
function getMin(array){
    return Math.min.apply(Math,array);
}

function getMax(array){
    return Math.max.apply(Math,array);
}
```

And then you can call the functions passing the array:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var maximo = getMax(myArray); //return the highest number
```

Answer (score 9):

The following code works for me :

```
var valueList = [10,4,17,9,3];
var maxValue = valueList.reduce(function(a, b) { return Math.max(a, b); });
var minValue = valueList.reduce(function(a, b) { return Math.min(a, b); });
```

Answer (score 9):

> let arr=[20,8,29,76,7,21,9]
> Math.max.apply( Math, arr ); // 76

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to get the max value from an array of objects.  Create a copy (with slice), then sort the copy in descending order and grab the first item.

```
var myArray = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 500}
]

maxsort = myArray.slice(0).sort(function(a, b) { return b.ID - a.ID })[0].ID;
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple stuff, really.

```
var arr = [10,20,30,40];
arr.max = function() { return  Math.max.apply(Math, this); }; //attach max funct
arr.min = function() { return  Math.min.apply(Math, this); }; //attach min funct

alert("min: " + arr.min() + " max: " + arr.max());
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `Math.max()` or `Math.min()`

```
Math.max(10, 20);   //  20
Math.min(-10, -20); // -20
```

The following function uses `Function.prototype.apply()` to find the maximum element in a numeric array. `getMaxOfArray([1, 2, 3])` is equivalent to `Math.max(1, 2, 3)`, but you can use `getMaxOfArray()` on programmatically constructed arrays of any size.

```
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
```

Or with the new spread operator, getting the maximum of an array becomes a lot easier.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var max = Math.max(...arr); // 3
var min = Math.min(...arr); // 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use lodash's methods

```
_.max([4, 2, 8, 6]);
returns => 8
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#max

```
_.min([4, 2, 8, 6]);
returns => 2
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#min

Comment: This solution works with large arrays. Does not give the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 5):

### Finding the Max and Min elements of an array in JavaScript.

There are several approaches you can use:

##### Using [**`Math.min()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [**`Math.max()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```
let array = [100, 0, 50];
Math.min(...array); // 0
Math.max(...array); // 100
```

##### Using [`Sorting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted)

```
let array = [100, 0, 50];
arraySorted = array.toSorted((a, b) => a - b); // [0, 50, 100];
arraySorted.at(0);  // 0
arraySorted.at(-1); // 100
```

#### Using simple for-loop

```
let array = [100, 0, 50];
let maxNumber = array[0];
let minNumber = array[0];
for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] > maxNumber) {
    maxNumber = array[i];
  }
  if (array[i] < minNumber) {
    minNumber = array[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ChaosPandion's solution works if you're using protoype. If not, consider this:

```
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};

Array.min = function( array ){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};
```

The above will return NaN if an array value is not an integer so you should build some functionality to avoid that.  Otherwise this will work.

Comment: jeerose, why do you have (Math, this) as agruments when Roatin Marth only has (null, this)?

Comment: @HankH: see my response to your comment in a comment to my own answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "ChaosPandion's solution works if you're using protoype". How is your solution different, except you're using the `Math` object as the context?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you extend the prototype yours will work. Apologies.

Comment: So which is better, jeerose or ChaosPandion's?

Comment: what about "Array.prototype.max = function(){
 return Math.max.apply({},this)
}"

Comment: This looks oddly familiar to what @inkedmn posted, down to the syntax spacing and bracketing. Only his has a link to his reference (also oddly familiar). Hmmmm ;)

Comment: Okay right you are Roatin; I should have referenced it.  My mistake for sure.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the library [**sugar.js**](http://sugarjs.com/), you can write [**arr.min()**](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/min) and [**arr.max()**](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/max) as you suggest. You can also get min and max values from non-numeric arrays.

> **min( map , all = false )** Returns the element in the array with the
> lowest value. map may be a function mapping the value to be checked or
> a string acting as a shortcut. If all is true, will return all min
> values in an array.
>
> **max( map , all = false )** Returns the element in the array with the
> greatest value. map may be a function mapping the value to be checked
> or a string acting as a shortcut. If all is true, will return all max
> values in an array.

Examples:

```
[1,2,3].min() == 1
['fee','fo','fum'].min('length') == "fo"
['fee','fo','fum'].min('length', true) == ["fo"]
['fee','fo','fum'].min(function(n) { return n.length; }); == "fo"
[{a:3,a:2}].min(function(n) { return n['a']; }) == {"a":2}
['fee','fo','fum'].max('length', true) == ["fee","fum"]
```

Libraries like [**Lo-Dash**](http://lodash.com/docs#min) and [**underscore.js**](http://underscorejs.org/#min) also provide similar powerful min and max functions:

Example from Lo-Dash:

```
_.max([4, 2, 8, 6]) == 8
var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 40 }
];
_.max(characters, function(chr) { return chr.age; }) == { 'name': 'fred', 'age': 40 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
let max= a=> a.reduce((m,x)=> m>x ? m:x);
let min= a=> a.reduce((m,x)=> m<x ? m:x);
```

```js
let max= a=> a.reduce((m,x)=> m>x ? m:x);
let min= a=> a.reduce((m,x)=> m<x ? m:x);

// TEST - pixel buffer
let arr = Array(200*800*4).fill(0); 
arr.forEach((x,i)=> arr[i]=100-i%101); 

console.log('Max', max(arr));
console.log('Min', min(arr))
```

For Math.min/max (+apply) we get error:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded (Chrome 74.0.3729.131)

```js
// TEST - pixel buffer
let arr = Array(200*800*4).fill(0); 
arr.forEach((x,i)=> arr[i]=100-i%101); 

// Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded

try {
  let max1= Math.max(...arr);          
} catch(e) { console.error('Math.max :', e.message) }

try {
  let max2= Math.max.apply(null, arr); 
} catch(e) { console.error('Math.max.apply :', e.message) }


// same for min
```

Answer (score 4):

In this day and age (in 2022), the most efficient way to get `min` + `max` from an array is to do it in a single iteration, via `reduce`.

- In JavaScript:

```js
const arr = [3, 0, -2, 5, 9, 4];

const i = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
    p.min = c < p.min ? c : p.min ?? c;
    p.max = c > p.max ? c : p.max ?? c;
    return p;
}, {min: undefined, max: undefined});

console.log(i); //=> { min: -2, max: 9 }
```

And when the input has no data, it will output `{min: undefined, max: undefined}`.

In TypeScript, you would just add type casting, so the return type is inferred as `{min: number | undefined, max: number | undefined}`, and not as `{min: any, max: any}`:

```
const arr = [3, 0, -2, 5, 9, 4];

const i = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
    p.min = c < p.min! ? c : p.min ?? c;
    p.max = c > p.max! ? c : p.max ?? c;
    return p;
}, {min: undefined, max: undefined} as { min: number | undefined, max: number | undefined });

console.log(i); //=> { min: -2, max: 9 }
```

**UPDATE**

Following `kiran goud` comment, here's an alternative that uses arrays instead of objects:

```js
const i = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[0] = c < p[0] ? c : p[0] ?? c;
    p[1] = c > p[1] ? c : p[1] ?? c;
    return p;
}, [undefined, undefined]);

console.log(i); //=> [-2, 9]
```

Comment: We can avoid Objects, undefined and comparators here
`
arr.reduce((p, c) => {
                        return [Math.min(p[0], c), Math.max(p[1], c)]
                    }, [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER])
`

Comment: @kirangoud It will produce an invalid result when `arr` is empty, plus `Math` performance would be slower.

Comment: @kirangoud I have added an update there for use of arrays ;)

Comment: Casting the undefineds to number will give the wrong typing when the array is empty

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt It was easy to correct - see updated example for TypeScript ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
let arr = [2,5,3,5,6,7,1];

let max = Math.max(...arr); // 7
let min = Math.min(...arr); // 1
```

Comment: This solution has already been provided by multiple other answerers to this question. What does your answer add?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **prototype.js** framework, then this code will work ok:

```
arr.min();
arr.max();
```

Documented here: [Javascript prototype framework for max](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/max)

Answer (score 2):

```
minHeight = Math.min.apply({},YourArray);
minKey    = getCertainKey(YourArray,minHeight);
maxHeight = Math.max.apply({},YourArray);
maxKey    = getCertainKey(YourArray,minHeight);
function getCertainKey(array,certainValue){
   for(var key in array){
      if (array[key]==certainValue)
         return key;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plain vanilla JS approach.

```
function getMinArrayVal(seq){
    var minVal = seq[0];
    for(var i = 0; i<seq.length-1; i++){
        if(minVal < seq[i+1]){
        continue;
        } else {
        minVal = seq[i+1];
        }
    }
    return minVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.sort but you'll have to write a simple number sorting function since the default is alphabetic.

[Look at example 2 here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Then you can grab `arr[0]` and `arr[arr.length-1]` to get min and max.

Comment: The question is about min/max, not sorting.

Comment: @Ates Goral - certainly, but surely you can understand that a sorted list allows O(1) access to the min and max values, yes?

Comment: Performance wise the sort would have a lot more swapping going on. That has to come in to consideration.

Comment: I agree that sorting is a simple approach that works; however, the performance concerns that @ChaosPandion pointed out are real.

Answer (score 1):

create a simple object

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray = [10,12,14,100];

var getMaxHeight = {
     hight : function( array ){ return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
}

getMaxHeight.hight(myArray);
```

Comment: why do you actually need an object for that? It's just a function that you're using in the end. And also, why are you defining your array twice?

Comment: The main solution  here is not the array creation convention or assign value to a variable. You can use create array in any you want and assign value as you wish.

Comment: I know it is not **the main solution**. In fact it isn't even part of the solution. If it were, maybe i'd down-voted you, but I didn't. I was just curious about why did you write the code that way.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Linus's reduce() approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13440842/558639), especially for large arrays.  But as long as you know you need both min and the max, why iterate over the array twice?

```
Array.prototype.minmax = function () {
  return this.reduce(function (p, v) {
    return [(p[0] < v ? p[0] : v), (p[1] > v ? p[1] : v)];
  }, [this[0], this[0]]);
}
```

Of course, if you prefer the iterative approach, you can do that too:

```
Array.prototype.minmax = function () {
    var mn = this[0], mx = this[0];
    this.forEach(function (v) {
        if (v < mn) mn = v;
        if (v > mx) mx = v;
    });
    return [mn, mx];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent "max" and "min" to be listed in a "for ... in" loop:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "max", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,    
    value: function() {
        return Math.max.apply(null, this);
    }
});
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "min", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,    
    value: function() {
        return Math.min.apply(null, this);
    }
});
```

**Usage:**

```
var x = [10,23,44,21,5];
x.max(); //44
x.min(); //5
```

Answer (score 1):

Below script worked for me in ndoejs:

```
 var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
 console.log('Value:: ' + Math.max.apply(null, numbers) ); // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

well I would like to do this in the below way

```
const findMaxAndMin = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length <= 0) return -1;
  let min = arr[0];
  let max = arr[0];
  arr.forEach((n) => {
    n > max ? (max = n) : false;
    n < min ? (min = n) : false;
  });
  return [min, max];
};
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `map` if you're not using the output. Consider using `forEach` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
   let arr = [1,10,25,15,31,5,7,101];
    let sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)

    let min = sortedArr[0];
    let max = sortedArr[arr.length-1]

    console.log(`min => ${min}. Max => ${max}`)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

To add to the many good answers here, here is a typescript version that can handle lists where some values are `undefined`.

How it can be used:

```
const testDates = [
  undefined,
  new Date('July 30, 1986'),
  new Date('July 31, 1986'),
  new Date('August 1, 1986'),
]
const max: Date|undefined = arrayMax(testDates); // Fri Aug 01 1986
const min: Date|undefined = arrayMin(testDates); // Min: Wed Jul 30 1986
const test: Date = arrayMin(testDates); // Static type error
const anotherTest: undefined = arrayMin(testDates); // Static type error
```

The definitions (the `notEmpty` definition is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700791/1720199)):

```
function arrayMax<T>(values?: (T | null | undefined)[]): T | undefined {
    const nonEmptyValues = filterEmpty(values);
    if (nonEmptyValues.length === 0) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return nonEmptyValues.reduce((a, b) => (a >= b ? a : b), nonEmptyValues[0]);
}

function arrayMin<T>(values?: (T | null | undefined)[]): T | undefined {
    const nonEmptyValues = filterEmpty(values);
    if (nonEmptyValues.length === 0) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return nonEmptyValues.reduce((a, b) => (a <= b ? a : b), nonEmptyValues[0]);
}

function filterEmpty<T>(values?: (T | null | undefined)[] | null): T[] {
    return values?.filter(notEmpty) ?? [];
}

function notEmpty<T>(value: T | null | undefined): value is T {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) return false;
    const testDummy: T = value;
    return true;
}
```

I didn't use the `Math.max` function as [suggested in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#getting_the_maximum_element_of_an_array) because this way I can use this function with any comparable objects (if you know how to type this let me know so I can better define `T`).

Answer (score 0):

If you need performance then this is the best way for small arrays:

```
var min = 99999;
var max = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
{
    if(v[i] < min)
    {
        min = v[i];
    }
    if(v[i] >= max)
    {
        max = v[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the numbers seperated by a comma and click on the event you want to call ie Get the Max or min number.

```js
        function maximumNumber() {
       
            var numberValue = document.myForm.number.value.split(",");
            var numberArray = [];
    
            for (var i = 0, len = numberValue.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    
                numberArray.push(+numberValue[i]);
    
                var largestNumber = numberArray.reduce(function (x, y) {
                    return (x > y) ? x : y;
                });
            }
    
            document.getElementById("numberOutput").value = largestNumber;
    
        }
    
        function minimumNumber() {
  
            var numberValue = document.myForm.number.value.split(",");
            var numberArray = [];
    
            for (var i = 0, len = numberValue.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    
                numberArray.push(+numberValue[i]);
    
                var smallestNumber = numberArray.reduce(function (x, y) {
                    return (x < y) ? x : y;
                });
            }
    
            document.getElementById("numberOutput").value = smallestNumber;
    
        }
    
    
            function restrictCharacters(evt) {
    
                evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
                var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
                if (((charCode >= '48') && (charCode <= '57')) || (charCode == '44')) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

```html
    <div>    
            <form name="myForm">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Insert Number</td>
               
                <td><input type="text" name="number" id="number" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(event);" /></td>
                
                <td><input type="button" value="Maximum" onclick="maximumNumber();" /></td>
                
                <td><input type="button" value="Minimum" onclick="minimumNumber();"/></td>
                
                <td><input type="text" id="numberOutput" name="numberOutput" /></td>
    
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have complex object, you could use sort....such as: if I want get item which contains MAX/MIN value of below objs.

```
var objs= [
{name:"Apple",value:3},
{name:"Love",value:32},
{name:"Cheese",value:1},
{name:"Pork",value:77},
{name:"Xmas",value:99}        
];
```

I will do a sort:

```
objs.sort(function(a, b){return a.value-b.value});
```

Then:
`objs[0]` is the MIN, `objs[objs.length-1]` is the MAX.

Comment: the `sort` actually update the array, like mentionned in @Ben answer. OP is only about getting the min/max value.

Comment: you could make a copy of the current array sort it and get min/max. Few extra lines of code. However, i was just trying to post an alternative solution. lol. And the array i was working on has 3 levels of objects, i have to get min/max from the 2nd level. It was not just to get min/max from single valued array.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to add methods to the Array prototype, which may conflict with other libraries.

I've seen a lot of examples use forEach which, I wouldn't recommend for large arrays due to its poor performance vs a for loop. https://coderwall.com/p/kvzbpa/don-t-use-array-foreach-use-for-instead

Also `Math.max(Math, [1,2,3]);` Always gives me NaN?

```
function minArray(a) {
  var min=a[0]; for(var i=0,j=a.length;i<j;i++){min=a[i]<min?a[i]:min;}
  return min;
}

function maxArray(a) {
  var max=a[0]; for(var i=0,j=a.length;i<j;i++){max=a[i]>max?a[i]:max;}
  return max;
}

minArray([1,2,3]); // returns 1
```

If you have an array of objects the minArray() function example below will accept 2 parameters, the first is the array and the second is the key name for the object key value to compare. The function in this case would return the index of the array that has the smallest given key value.

```
function minArray(a, key) {
  var min, i, j, index=0;
  if(!key) {
    min=a[0]; 
    for(i=0,j=a.length;i<j;i++){min=a[i]<min?a[i]:min;}
    return min;
  }
  min=a[0][key];
  for(i=0,j=a.length;i<j;i++){
    if(a[i][key]<min) {
      min = a[i][key];
      index = i;
    }
  }
    return index;
}

var a = [{fee: 9}, {fee: 2}, {fee: 5}];

minArray(a, "fee"); // returns 1, as 1 is the proper array index for the 2nd array element.
```

Comment: Why is this the top answer? The top one should be http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669222/390014

Comment: Yes I'd agree to use the Math.min.apply() for finding the minimum primitive array value, I recall seeing comments leaving out the apply call which gave me the null response which is why I came up with the first solution. Though my second solution should still hold merit for object arrays, of course unless there's a better one :)

Answer (score 0):

linear, almost-purely-functional-approach

```
var min=[0, 29, 25].map((function(max) {max=-Infinity; return function(e) {return max=Math.max(max, e);}})())[0]
```

---

More examples:

Finding out *min* value

```
function getMin(arr) {
    return (ar || [0, 29, 25]).
        map((function(max) {max=-Infinity; return function(e) {return max=Math.max(max, e);}})())[0];
}
```

or using `Array.map` method with variable closuring

```
function getMin(arrObjs) {
    return (arrObjs || [{val: 0}, {val: 29}, {val: 25}]).
        map((function(max) {max=-Infinity; return function(e) {return max=(max.val>e.val?max:e);}})())[0];
}
```

Finding out *max* value

```
function getMax(arr) {
    return (ar || [0, 29, 25]).
        map((function(v) {v=Infinity; return function(e) {return v=Math.min(v, e);}})())[0];
}
```

for array of objects

```
function getMax(arrObjs) {
    return (arrObjs || [{val: 0}, {val: 29}, {val: 25}]).
        map((function(v) {v=-Infinity; return function(e) {return v=(v.val<e.val?v:e);}})())[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution to the problem

```js
const findMinMax = (arr, max, min, i) => arr.length === i ? {
    min,
    max
  } :
  findMinMax(
    arr,
    arr[i] > max ? arr[i] : max,
    arr[i] < min ? arr[i] : min,
    ++i)

const arr = [5, 34, 2, 1, 6, 7, 9, 3];
const max = findMinMax(arr, arr[0], arr[1], 0)
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Solns

```
class SmallestIntegerFinder {
  findSmallestInt(args) {
    return args.reduce((min,item)=>{ return (min<item ? min : item)});
  }
}

class SmallestIntegerFinder {
  findSmallestInt(args) {
    return Math.min(...args)
  }
}

class SmallestIntegerFinder {
  findSmallestInt(args) {
    return Math.min.apply(null, args);
  }
}

class SmallestIntegerFinder {
  findSmallestInt(args) {
    args.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b; } )
    return args[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For learning purpose, you can do it by using variables and for loop without using built-in functions.

```js
// Input sample data to the function
var arr = [-1, 0, 3, 100, 99, 2, 99];
// Just to show the result
console.log(findMinMax(arr));

function findMinMax(arr) {
  let arraySize = arr.length;
  if (arraySize > 0) {
    var MaxNumber = MinNumber = arr[0];
    for (var i = 0; i <= arraySize; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > MaxNumber) {
        MaxNumber = arr[i];
      }else if(arr[i] < MinNumber) {
        MinNumber = arr[i];
      }
    }
    var minMax = [MinNumber,MaxNumber];
    return minMax;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one more example. Calculate the Max/Min value from an array with **[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#over)**.

```js
let array = [100, 0, 50];
var func = _.over(Math.max, Math.min);
var [max, min] = func(...array);
// => [100, 0]
console.log(max);
console.log(min);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -9):

I managed to solve my problem this way:

```
    var strDiv  = "4,8,5,1"
var arrayDivs   = strDiv.split(",")
var str = "";

for (i=0;i<arrayDivs.length;i++)
{
    if (i<arrayDivs.length-1)
    {
      str = str + eval('arrayDivs['+i+']')+',';
    } 
    else if (i==arrayDivs.length-1)
    {
      str = str + eval('arrayDivs['+i+']');
    }
}

str = 'Math.max(' + str + ')';
    var numMax = eval(str);
```

I hope I have helped.

Best regards.