# Writing a program to find the maximum value in an array

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

```
var test = [-42, 0, 8];
var biggest=-Infinity;
for (i=0; i<test.length;i++)
{if (test[i]>biggest)
    alert('It is!');
  biggest = test[i];
 else
     alert("It isn't!");}
alert("The biggest element is:" + biggest);
```

I'm trying to write a program to find the biggest number in an array but my code is not working. Any help please?

Comment: @darvids0n You beat me by 6 seconds. :)

Comment: `test.sort()[test.length-1]`, just another idea if you're shure it's all numbers.

Comment: @KooiInc: What about `pop()` ?

Comment: @alex: that's all right too, yep. And `unshift()` then for the lowest value.

Comment: @KooiInc: `sort()` converts to strings first, then sorts lexicographically, so you will get not a numeric sort. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/te4mJ/).

Comment: @alex, ok: [somearray].sort(function(a,b){return Number(a)-Number(b);}).pop()` should prevent that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have been bitten by the "too few braces" bug:

```
if (test[i]>biggest)
    alert('It is!');
    biggest = test[i]; // THIS IS NOT INSIDE THE IF!
```

If you fix this, [it works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/WfCaW/).

Of course, you can do this much easier using `Math.Max`, as this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) sample shows:

```
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
```

Comment: This is why I *always* require braces on conditionals... +1

Comment: @pst: It's one of those "yeah I know you can do this without braces, but shut up and just use them anyway" issues for me too.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit clever, but quite succinct and works well.

Just call [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and pass the array as the arguments.

```
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHWKe/).

Answer (score 1):

Although you should listen to @alex, this is how you would have done it if there were no `Math.max`, and you wanted to code C-style:

```
var test = [-42, 0, 8];

var biggest = -Infinity;

for(var i = 0; i < test.length; ++i)
    if(test[i] > biggest)
        biggest = test[i];

alert("The biggest element is:" + biggest);
```

Comment: Use of `prop in array` .... generally ick.

Comment: @pst Huh? (I'm not much of a JavaScript programmer.)

Comment: @muntoo: It will iterate over all enumerable properties in the object, including the prototype chain. Generally unfavorable when dealing with an `Array`, you want only the numerical indices.

Comment: @alex So when *would* you use `foreach()`?

Comment: @muntoo `Array.forEach` in ECMAScript ed5, `for(i=0;i<len;i++)` for EMCAScript ed3 (or whatever function said favorite library provides ;-) This problem is actually well-suited for `Array.reduce` aka fold, also in ed5.

Comment: @muntoo: `forEach` is different to `for ( in )` again. :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution

```
function nsort(a,b){
    return a - b;
}
var test = [-42, 0, 8, 3, 15, 12],
    max  = test.sort(nsort).pop(); // 15
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TkeHb/

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript 5th Edition introduces a few higher-order functions for arrays -- yay!.

One is [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (also known as [left fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)):

Thus, this can be solved as:

```
var arr = [-42, 0, 8]
var res = arr.reduce(function (prev,cur) {
   return cur > prev ? cur : prev
}, -Infinity)
res // 8
```

Not nearly as "elegant" in this case as applying the array as the parameters to `Math.max`, but higher-order functions can make good additions to a "toolbox" ;-) Consider the slight modification to find the longest string in an array:

```
var arr = ["Hello", "World!!!", "Wut?"]
var res = arr.reduce(function (prev,cur) {
   return cur.length > prev.length ? cur : prev
}, "")
res // "World!!!"
```

Try *that* with `Math.max` or `Array.sort` and index/pop ;-)

Happy coding.

---

While the above is for 5th Edition, a trivial reduce function can be written for ECMAScript 3rd Edition (aka JavaScript 1.5) and equivalent functionality is part of a number of libraries:

```
function reduce (arr, fn, v) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    v = fn(v, arr[i])
  }
  return v
}
// used as:
reduce(arr, function (prev,cur) { ... }, initValue)
```

(This could be added to the Array prototype, but I consider mucking with core prototypes fairly ugly.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the modern methods to do this.