# how to find the maximum length of an option using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a select with options, its a transformed select not the normal one.

```
<select>
<option value="0">apple</option>
<option value="1">orange</option>
<option value="2">bannan fruit</option>
</select>
```

How to find the maximum length in the options(bannan fruit) using Jquery?

Comment: @Simon Yes the string of bannana fruit which is the biggest text in options...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var max_length = -1;
$('option').each(function(){
  max_length = Math.max(max_length, $(this).text().length);
});
alert(max_length);
```

Comment: Just need to change `.val()` to `.text()`.

Comment: @Dogbert I tried of using max_length = Math.max(max_length, $(this).width()); It worked in FF, but in IE the width remains 0...

Answer (score 2):

Mandatory one-liner solution:

```
Math.max.apply(null, $('option').map(function() { return $(this).html().length; }).toArray())
```

I'd say that Dogbert's solution is probably more readable, but there might still be some fun lessons in here. What's going on:

- using [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get a result set of just the lengths
- using [`.toArray`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) to make an actual array out of the result set, which would be required by `.apply`
- Passing the array to `Math.max` using `apply` which will make the second argument the `arguments` collection, i.e. equivalent of writing `Math.max(5, 6, 12);`

If you're using [Roatin Marth's excellent array extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1669222/133802), the code would look a bit neater:

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this)
}

$('option').map(function() { return $(this).html().length; }).toArray().max();
```

Comment: +1 mandatory up-vote for adequate language feature usage. (`.toArray()` is *correct*, but superfluous, sind the jQuery object actually *is* an array - and I guess it should be `.text()` instead of `.html()`)

Answer (score 1):

You can prototype jQuery object like this:

```
jQuery.prototype.select_longest = function () { 
    var res = ""; 
    $(this).children().each(function () {
        if ($(this).html().length > res.length) 
            res = $(this).html(); 
    }); 
    return res;        // use this line if you want biggest string
    return res.length; // use this line if you want length of biggest string
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var longest = $("#id").select_longest();
```