# How to find the Max and Min value of a scalar?

Tags: javascript, vector, max, min

Okay, so I'm trying to use Javascript to make a Game (Engine?Maybe...). Unfortunately, that means no extremely detailed library like in Visual C#...

So I'm wondering, if I have vector (which is just two variables for right now) and I make that a scalar(multiply those two numbers) then how to i find the min and the max of this scalar?

C#/XNA has a built in Min() and Max(), but I'm trying to do this in Javascript I couldn't seem to find anything on this site, the similar questions on the side don't seem to be of any help... I don't have any code for you because I'm not sure where to start... can someone please help?

[Vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29) and 
[Scalars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: ... unless I am seriously confused, a scalar is a single value so the notion of min and max of a scalar makes no sense.  What do you really mean?

Comment: hackartist, see the two links i put up, this isn't the scalar used in computing, it's the mathematical term (basically a vector multiplied by something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript also has built in Max and Min functions, e.g.,

```
var bigNum = Math.max(1,2,3,4,5);
```

These can be extended to get Max and Min values in arrays (vectors).  See this question:
[JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: sooo... do I just find the min and max out of the two values of the scalar? that sounds simplistic enough... It looked like higher level math so I was really confused (I'm taking Pre-Calc this year, I'm in High School)