# javascript looping of linked list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function to find the smallest value in linkedlist using javascript. However, my code doesn't seem to work. I guess there's something wrong with the while loop. My code as follows:

```
function find_smallest(ll){
    var i = ll;
    var smallest = i.data;
    while(i){
        if(i.data<smallest){
             smallest = i.data;
        }
        i.next;
    }
    return i.data;
}
```

Comment: just as a matter of practicality -- you're setting yourself up for failure by naming your parameter "ll".  The font makes it look like "eleven".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669222/871580 Have a look at this. You might need to convert data using a method such as  Array.prototype.slice.call(data, 0) to convert data to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your i should now be pointing to i.next after every iteration:

```
function find_smallest(ll){
var i = ll;
var smallest = i.data;
while(i){
   if(i.data<smallest){
         smallest = i.data;
    }
    i = i.next;//not i.next;
}
return i.data;//i think this is smallest not i.data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely forgot to advance your position.

```
function find_smallest(ll){
  var i = ll;
  var smallest = i.data;
  while(i) {
     if(i.data < smallest){
           smallest = i.data;
      }
      i = i.next; // <== here
  }
  return smallest;
}
```

And you have just `i.next`. You need an assignment. Also, your code would raise an error in the end, because you're referring to `i.data` and `i` would be `null` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

What is `i.next`?

A **function**?

```
i.next();
```

A **variable**?

```
i = i.next;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return 'smallest' and not 'i.data'. That will always return the last value in the linked list.