# concat function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to pick highest value from an array so i use math.max function it is working well when i run this only with one array but as i have two different array to first of all i want to join them together so i use concat function but it is not working.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


<script type="text/javascript">

var maX=[6,1]

var miN=[10,20]

alert(Math.max.apply(maX.concat(miN))


</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply` receives two arguments: the "this" and the argument list. Try

```
Math.max.apply(null, maX.concat(miN) )
```

or

```
Math.max.apply(Math, maX.concat(miN) )
```

Comment: i give them two argument but it is not wokring alert(Math.max.apply(null,maX.concat(miN))

Comment: @amit You need one more closing bracket.

Comment: @amit: It works for me. Are you using IE by any chance? Also, use the developer console and console.log to test stuff like this instead of `alert`. Its better in many ways.

Comment: yes you are right sir, thank u so much, sir one more help i required from your side. actully i am new to this field so i did not aware about console log and developer console can u tell me something about it and how to use it

Comment: Depends on what browser you are using. In crome, IE and Safari just press F12. In Firefox you need to download the Firebug addon.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `apply` is the value of `this`, not a parameter.  Try

```
Math.max.apply(Math, maX.concat(miN))
```

Answer (score 0):

to concat two arrays: `var joinedarray = array1.concat(array2)`

then do max on the joinedarray
EDIT: to do the Math.max on the array refference this answer: [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: If you pass an array to max you just get NaN back

Comment: correct to do the Math.max on the array refference this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values

Answer (score 0):

The following code concatenates two arrays:

```
var alpha = ["a", "b", "c"];  
var numeric = [1, 2, 3];  

// creates array ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]; alpha and numeric are unchanged  
var alphaNumeric = alpha.concat(numeric);
```

The following code concatenates three arrays:

```
var num1 = [1, 2, 3];  
var num2 = [4, 5, 6];  
var num3 = [7, 8, 9];



// creates array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; num1, num2, num3 are unchanged  


 var nums = num1.concat(num2, num3);
```

The following code concatenates three values to an array:

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c'];  

// creates array ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3], leaving alpha unchanged  
var alphaNumeric = alpha.concat(1, [2, 3]);
```