# Automatically Generate max 'N' values from javascript array

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)
>   [Generate max 'N' values from javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617982/generate-max-n-values-from-javascript-array)

```
var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

How to execute 5 max values from this array?
result must be like
`10, 9, 8, 7, 6`

Comment: is this homework and what have you already tried?

Comment: please take into account suggestions and comments you were given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617982/generate-max-n-values-from-javascript-array

Comment: @jsobo this is example, I have array with length more than 1,000,000, and I want to take 5 max values.

Comment: I know how to get min and max, but how to get 5 max's in one function?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Arrays Java API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). It'll give you some practice in reading up on documentation as well as give you methods to use to solve the homework problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this 
1. first you arrange Array in ascending order. 
2. get it's Length.
3. get last 5 Digits whose u have required.

i thinks this is helpful to you.
..! cheers