# JavaScript: max of an array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code: http://jsfiddle.net/MvWV7/5/

What I'm trying to achieve is that user should fill the inputs starting with 1. After the user types 1 the next value must be 2 (not nanother number) and so on.

I'm trying to fill the inputs values in an array by doing this (as shown in the fiddle):

```
var ary = [];   
$(".activity_order").not(self).each(function(t) {ary.push(this.value);})
```

but when I do

```
ary.max()
```

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object ,,,,,,,, has no method 'max'
```

In console when I do `ary.max()` i get 0 if there's no numbers

**UPDATE**

My fault, I was using google console in jsfiddle and I started to look up for array methods inside.
When I did ary.max() it gives 0

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1669190/875127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're presumably typing `[].max` into the console on the jsfiddle domain. Note the output:

```javascript
function () {
    return Math.max.apply(null, this); // 'this' is your array
}
```

The reason here is that code on the jsfiddle domain has modified the prototype of `Array` to include the `max` method. It's mapped to the `Math.max` method and doesn't natively reside on the `Array` object itself, or its prototype.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Actually your response is correct according to my question :D

Answer (score 0):

An array does not have a `.max()` method.   If you want to create one, you will have to write or procure a function to iterate through an array and find the largest value in the array.

As it turns out, you can use the `Math.max()` function to solve this problem like this:

```
var m = Math.max.apply(null, ary);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Array* does not have a `max` method. But there is `Math.max` that you can use for this.

`var m = Math.max.apply(0, ary);`

The reason why you cannot call it like `Math.max(ary)` is that `Math.max` accepts a series of values instead of an array. Calling using `apply`, converts the second array argument into a sequence of arguments.

Comment: `Math.max()` doesn't take an array as an argument.  It takes one or more individual arguments.

Comment: `Math.max` is a function, and as such its prototype has the `apply` method which does in fact accept an array. @jfriend00 You are technically in error here. I'm upvoting on that basis.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - Corrected the answer. But.. i was always under the impression that `apply` **only** dictates the values of `this` inside the function.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - as you can see in the answer I supplied, there is a way to use `.apply()` with `Math.max()` but that turns an array into successive arguments which Math.max does accept.  You can't pass an array like this: `Math.max(arr)` which is what I said and why this answer is wrong..

Comment: `.apply()` both sets the value of `this` and turns an array into successive arguments passed to the function which is what you needed here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `.max` and `.min` don't exist. They aren't methods, just like the thrown error says.

You would have to modify the array prototype to do something in the syntax you provided.

This was already discussed here: [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `max()` and `min()` methods in array object natively. You should add them before trying to use it.

```
Array.prototype.min = function () {
  return this.reduce(function (p, v) {
    return ( p < v ? p : v );
  });
}

Array.prototype.max = function () {
  return this.reduce(function (p, v) {
    return ( p > v ? p : v );
  });
}
```

Here is [working fork of your's code](http://jsfiddle.net/MvWV7/6/) with this methods added.