# Return Maximum value from a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, max

I have an associative array which looks like:

```
var data = {
    0: {
        'Number_of_Something': 212
    },
    1: {
        'Number_of_Something': 65
    },
    2: {
        'Number_of_Something': 657
    }
}
```

I need to extract the highest value in the field `Number_of_Something`, however, because it is a field within an object of an object, it is a little more complicated than just following a similar method to something outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values).

Looping through the object and storing the value, then replacing it if the next one is larger seems like the easiest and obvious option.

**I am simply asking this question in case there is a simpler (smarter) way of achieving this other than the method outlined above?**

Comment: Why is `data` an object and not an array or at least array-like object?

Comment: @FelixKling it is a JSON object passed from a PHP script. I force an object for other purposes :)

Comment: What is wrong with looping over the object members? That seems pretty simple, maintainable and very compatible to me.

Comment: @RobG Absolutely nothing wrong with it, but I just wanted to check there were not any javascript functions already there that would make the process simpler :-)

Comment: I don't see how nesting 3 functions is simpler that basic loop. A little less code perhaps, but certainly not simpler. Performance [seems mixed](http://jsperf.com/nesting-vs-loop), it doesn't seem any faster on balance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*simpler* can be subjective...
Another way to achieve what you ask is to get an array of the values using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and use the other solution with *Math.max* that you linked  :

```
var data = {
    0: {
        'Number_of_Something': 212
    },
    1: {
        'Number_of_Something': 65
    },
    2: {
        'Number_of_Something': 657
    }
}

var max = Math.max.apply(null,
                        Object.keys(data).map(function(e) {
                                return data[e]['Number_of_Something'];
                        }));
```

Comment: It will need shims for missing ES5 features like *Object.keys* and *map*.

Comment: How can I return the index of the item with the highest number?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own (for) loop and return the max value that way. Another option is to use a library like [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to handle this for you and keep your code readable.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So, in short, without a plugin there is no short easy way, I need to loop through as I suggested in my question?

Comment: Well...a plugin will also loop through the object/array internally. There is no other solution.

Comment: Thought so :-). I have accepted @Zapshu's solution as it provides exactly what I am looking for. Thanks anyway