# Max / min of large array in JS

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate min/max of large array. I know about `Math.max.apply()`, but on large arrays it fails with Stack overflow exception. Any simple solutions?

Comment: Obvious question: **How large?**

Comment: like 100 000 elements

Comment: Why are you processing data that large on the client side?

Comment: I didn't say anything about client side

Comment: True, but there are better ways to do it on the server side than Javascript, so I made an assumption. Why Javascript?

Comment: In fact it is a part of CLI script. My preference would be Python, but 1) my team decided to use JS
2) we use Azure and Windows, and node is easiest to setup to have cross-platform script tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Sort the array by using `sort()` method it sorts array by using quicksort algorithm
2. Since array is sorted in ascending order then the last element is the max

   ```js
   var arr = [1,4,6,4, ...];
   arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
   var max = arr[arr.length - 1];
   ```

Comment: You answer made me feel really stupid :(. In fact I already have sorted array. That's why you want code reviews...

Comment: Just keep it DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself :)

Comment: It's only worth sorting the array if you're going to be doing some binary searches [O(log n)] on the array anyways. If you want to get the max and min you might as well loop through every element since O(n) is faster than O(n log n). For lots of large arrays this might matter...

Comment: Sure. I have sorted array in order to calculate percentiles. Having min/max is a nice side effect :)

Comment: You can slightly simplify this by sorting in descending order, which allows just getting the first element. I.e. `arr.sort((a,  b) => b - a)[0]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Array.prototype.min = function() {
    var r = this[0];
    this.forEach(function(v,i,a){if (v<r) r=v;});
    return r;
};
```

From [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values) where other solutions from this problem are discussed

FYI: I just googled "max min large array" and found this as the first result...

Comment: I saw that thread, but didn't go through all of it, thanks :)

Comment: For reference, the exact answer there that addresses large arrays is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8986992/710446

Answer (score 2):

Why not just loop through the entire array?

```
var max = Number.MIN_VALUE, min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
for (var i = 0, len=list.length; i < len; i++) {
   if (list[i] > max) max = list[i];
   if (list[i] < min) min = list[i];
}
```

**Edit:**

For max:

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.GetMax === "undefined") {
    Array.prototype.GetMax = function() {
        var max = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        for (var i = 0, len=this.length; i < len; i++) {
           if (this[i] > max) max = this[i];
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

For min:

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.GetMin === "undefined") {
    Array.prototype.GetMin = function() {
        var min = Number.MIN_VALUE;
        for (var i = 0, len=this.length; i < len; i++) {
           if (this[i] < min) min = this[i];
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

For both:

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.GetMaxMin === "undefined") {
    Array.prototype.GetMaxMin = function() {
        var max = Number.MIN_VALUE, min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        for (var i = 0, len=this.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (this[i] > max) max = this[i];
            if (this[i] < min) min = this[i];
        }
        return { Max: max, Min: min};
    }
}
```

Comment: Just init `min`/`max` with `Number.MAX_VALUE`/`Number.MIN_VALUE`. Then you can drop the first if condition.

Comment: And this can be added to array.prototype to make it easier to use

Comment: I never knew Number.MAX_VALUE existed in javascript. Cool!

Comment: BTW, I'd initialize it using first element to support non-numeric values too

Answer (score 0):

Should I assume you have thought of this:

```
var maxSoFar = -9999999;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length ; ++i) {
    if (array[i] > maxSoFar) {
        maxSoFar = array[i];
    }
    ... similar for minSoFar ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought... I was looking for something more functional style :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=1000000;i>0;i--)
{
    arr.push(i);
}
//we create a copy of the original array through arr.concat() since we do not want to change the original sorting order of the array
//we pass a function in the sort method as by default it sorts alphabetically instead of numerically. So 99 will be smaller than 100.
var arrMaxMin = arr.concat().sort(function(a,b){return a-b});

arrMaxMin[0]; //min
arrMaxMin[arrMaxMin.length - 1]; //max
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey why dont you slice your array into smaller arrays then on that arrays you can easily use Math.max.apply(Math,individual arrays).But remember to reinitialize all subarrays back to null so as to get the memory back once desired max value is obtained

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is for:

```js
function max(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return NaN // or whatever answer you want for an empty array, or throw an error.
  }
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b), -Infinity)
}
console.log(max([...new Array(100000).keys()]))
```

(note that `[...new Array(100000).keys()]` is just a fancy way in a modern browsers to make a huge array of the numbers 0 to 999999. The `max` function itself will run in anything made in the last 20 years.)

You can also reduce it to this one-liner:

```js
arr.reduce((cur, val, i) => i === 0 ? val : Math.max(cur, val), NaN)
```

here `NaN` is the value you get back if the array is empty

Or even

```js
arr.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b), -Infinity)
```

although this will return `-Infinity` for an empty array.

Finally, it may be tempting to just do:

```js
arr.reduce(Math.max, -Infinity)  //don't do this!!
```

but this won't work. This is because `reduce` calls it's function (`Math.max`) with 4 parameters, one of which is the original array, so a `Math.max` on those will always result in a `NaN`.