# in javascript array find min max values

Tags: javascript

i have some arrays like this, the numbers in the array represents  slots numbers
       slots1 = {3,4,5,6}
       slots2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
       slots3 = {8,9,10}
      i am finding whether the selected slots are successive or not.
   first two arrays give correct min,max values.
  but the third array is giving min = 10, max=9.
   how to rectify it? 
i am finding maximum value like this

```
for(var s=0;s<no_slots;s++)//finding maximum value of slots array
        {    
             if(s == 0)
             { 
              var slots_max = slots[s];
             }
             else
             {
                    if(slots[s] > slots_max)
                    {
                      slots_max = slots[s];
                    }
             }              
        }
```

Comment: You should declare and initialize `slots_max` before your for loop...

Comment: You have a misprint, checking the **slots[s]** but iterating the **no_slots**

Comment: @mudalov - Actually, `no_slots` looks like it's just the length of the array.  `s` is the correct iterator variable.  Presumeably the line before the for loop looks like this: `var no_slots = slots.length;`

Comment: Oh, yes. Apologies for confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the JS `Math` Object:

For the minimum: `Math.min.apply(null,slots);`
For the maximum: `Math.max.apply(null,slots);`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you function is not correctly working for your third case. You probably missed something silly like initialization or something similar to that.
As I have modified your some code and it is returning correctly. You can also make it shorter.

```
var slots = [8, 9, 10]
var slots_max = slots[0];
for (var s = 0; s < slots.length; s++) //finding maximum value of slots array
{
   if (slots[s] > slots_max) {
         slots_max = slots[s];
      }
}
alert(slots_max);
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJRR7/)

Comment: Do we really require that else condition ? We can make that if (inside the else) stand- alone.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead try finding the minimum/maximum values using the Javascript `Math` library. This should return the correct result.

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, slots3);
var max = Math.max.apply(null, slots3);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1669222/1398245) for more details.