# extending array function getting this err "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'max'"

Tags: javascript

hello im trying to build this function into my code:

```
Array.max = function (array) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
};

Array.min = function (array) {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, array);
};
```

as dictated by:
[JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values). However when i try to call it using:

```
console.log(a.max());
```

where

```
a = [245, 3, 40, 89, 736, 19, 138, 240, 42]
```

I get the following Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'max'
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: this is not a duplicate especially since i obviously referenced the post!  this was more of an issue of js prototype programming not how to prototype are particular func

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add those functions in the prototype, not on the `Array` object itself.

```
Array.prototype.max = function () {
...

Array.prototype.min = function () {
...
```

Apart from that, to make your program work, you have to make the following changes

```
Array.prototype.max = function () {
    return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
    return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};
```

You want to call those functions on the current Array object, so, you have to use `this` variable instead of accepting an array as a parameter.

Comment: thx - i clearly picked the wrong answer.  still new to the whole 'prototype' concept as opposed to just adding methods