# how to get min and max of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

hey i cant figure out how to add students to an array and get the minimum and max value i know i gotta used math class but i dont know how in javaScript any ideas help would be awsome?

```
    var highestMark=0;
    var gradeAwarded;
    var StudentArr= [Student];
    var markArr = [mark];
    var Student = prompt("Enter Student Name: ", "Ross");
    var mark = prompt("Enter Student Mark: ", 50);
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, mark); /* This about equal to Math.max(numbers[0], ...) or Math.max(5, 6, ..) */
    var min = Math.min.apply(null, mark);
    if (mark <0 || mark >100){
alert("Grate out of bounds");
}else if (mark >= 83){
gradeAwarded = "A";
}else if (mark >= 70){
gradeAwarded = "B";
}else if (mark >= 50){
gradeAwarded = "C";
}else if (mark >= 0){
gradeAwarded = "F";
}

//document.write(Student + "  "+ gradeAwarded);
//document.write( '<br />' );

//document.write( Math.max(mark));
//document.write( Math.min(mark));

//for(var i=0;i<StudentArr.length;i++)
//document.write(Student[i]+mark[i]);
document.write(lowestMark);
//+'</td><td allign =*right*>'
//need to use push
```

Comment: The `java` tag doesn't belong on this question

Comment: Same question asked once.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values

Comment: didnt work thanks anyway is there a way to get the min or max value of the mark array with the math.max/min() function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var min = data.reduce(function(prev, cur) { return prev < cur ? prev : cur },data[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var b = arr.reduce(function(prev,next){ 
                  return prev > next ? prev:next
               });
b => 5
arr => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You need to give reduce an initial value for the accumulator.