# JavaScript: How to get min number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the minimum value from an array in JavaScript? I did try the Math.min method and it seems that it doesn't work as expected.

As an example, I have four divs with numeric values:

HTML:

```
<div id="r">3121</div>
<div id="g">2334</div>
<div id="b">3445</div>
<div id="a">4121</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var r = $('#r').text(),
    g = $('#g').text(),
    b = $('#b').text(),
    p = $('#a').text();

var mainBox = [r,g,b,a];
var minN = Math.min(mainBox);
alert(minN);
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values/1669222#1669222

Comment: This question isn't very good. Should read the documentation.

Comment: **Before you answer with this** `var minN = Math.min.apply(Math, mainBox);` - **please check it works because it doesn't** http://jsfiddle.net/V9Bwv/1/

Comment: .. **because** OP made a typo - a is undefined

Comment: @Popnoodles It will when the variables match: http://jsfiddle.net/V9Bwv/2/. :) The last variable was `p`, so it was pulling in an auto-global of the `<div>` itself with `a`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yes I eventually spotted the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2DEV/1/)

Use following code

```
//parseInt to convert String => Int.
var    r = parseInt($('#r').text(),10);
var    g = parseInt($('#g').text(),10);
var    b = parseInt($('#b').text(),10);
var    p = parseInt($('#a').text(),10);

//Here sort the values
var minN = Math.min(r,g,b,p);
alert(minN);
```

Comment: @Popnoodles ,Ok you can comment it out, no problem.

Comment: You should always pass the 10 radix to `parseInt` e.g. `parseInt(text, 10)`, otherwise it will parse numbers with leading 0's as octal etc! :)

Answer (score 4):

**Update answer: This solution is now working**

1. You have to do it with parseInt(..., 10).
2. The Math.min doesn't accept arrays.

So in your case you will have something like this:

```
function getMinFromArray (array_of_values) {
    return array_of_values.sort()[0];   
};

var r = parseInt($('#r').text(), 10),
    g = parseInt($('#g').text(), 10),
    b = parseInt($('#b').text(), 10),
    p = parseInt($('#a').text(), 10);

var mainBox = [r,g,b,a];
var result = getMinFromArray(mainBox);

alert(result);
```

This is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CJfWu/2/

Comment: ...because `text()` returns a string.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min

`min` doesn't accept an array.

Comment: I didn't downvote (better to comment), that gives NaN. http://jsfiddle.net/V9Bwv/

Comment: Removed -1. Now it's just the same as all the others.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can pass an array to `Math.min()` like that.

Try it like this:

```
var minValue = Math.min.apply(Math, mainBox);
```

Or just use it like this:

```
var minValue = Math.min(r,g,b,p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var r = parseInt($('#r').text(), 10),
    g = parseInt($('#g').text(), 10),
    b = parseInt($('#b').text(), 10),
    p = parseInt($('#a').text(), 10);

var minN=Math.min(r,g,b,p);
alert(minN);
```

As `.min()` does not accept array argument rather just comma separated integers, so you would place your integers one by one and it will return the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2J2L/1/):

```
var vals = [];
$('#r, #g, #b, #a').each(function(i){
    vals[i] = $(this).text();
});
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a general solution for any number of divs that contain numbers.
First, add a class for those divs with numbers as their text. For example, class="items".
Then use the following function to get the minimum values

```
var getMinValueForDivs = function (divsClass) {
    var itemDivs = $('.' + divsClass);
    var values = [];
    itemDivs.each(function (index, item) {
        values.push(item.innerHTML);
    });

    return Math.min.apply(this, values);
}
```

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    getMinValueForDivs('items'); 
});
```