# Finding min and max time in a set of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have a array of time as,

```
 var arr= ["17:30:48","19:30:48","18:30:48","19:30:48","17:40:48","19:10:48","17:10:48","19:30:45","17:13:48","19:13:48","17:30:48","19:28:48"];
```

I want to get the  min and max time out of these. tried if else but its becoming to lengthy by it.is there any easy way to do it.

Comment: [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it, take the first and last element.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: @ie. The solutions there only work for arrays of numbers.

Comment: @Barmar, solution there is quite common - just use the right comparer.

Comment: @ie. The solution there uses `Math.max`, not a comparer.

Comment: @Barmar, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669212/154896 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13440842/154896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99Eue/12/

Use this sort function and grab the first element.  That will get you the max.

```
arr.sort(function (a,b) {
    if(a > b) { return -1; }
    if(a < b) { return 1; }    
    return 0;
});

Console.log(arr[0]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var min = function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a <= b? a : b;});
};

var max = function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a <= b? b : a;});
};
```

`reduce` is faster but probably better to use good old `array.sort` for readability

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr= ["17:30:48","19:30:48","17:27:48","19:30:48","17:30:48","19:30:48","17:30:48","19:30:48","17:30:48","19:30:48","17:30:48","19:30:48"];

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return new Date('1970/01/01 ' + a) - new Date('1970/01/01 ' + b);
});

alert("Min: " + arr[0] + "     Max: " + arr[arr.length-1]);
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert them to dates instead of just comparing them as strings?