# Loop function not working for vowel counter. How can i make a counter text bold

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

My loop function for my vowels counter in not working correctly and I don't know where I have gone wrong I would like some assistance with it.

I am trying to get the most used vowel to be bold so say I have `A = 34 and E = 45` so E should be bold like this **E**

But I don't know whether I am missing some code or if I have got something wrong in my code.

This is my JavaScript.

```
 function countVowels() {

     var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

     var arrayOfLetters = text.split("");

     // These are the counters for the program to find the vowels.
     var countA = text.match(/[Aa]/g).length;
     var countE = text.match(/[Ee]/g).length;
     var countI = text.match(/[Ii]/g).length;
     var countO = text.match(/[Oo]/g).length;
     var countU = text.match(/[Uu]/g).length;
     var countComma = text.match(/[,.!": ;?)(]/g).length;

     var bold = "<strong>";
     var vowels = new Array();
     vowels[0] = "countA";
     vowels[1] = "countE";
     vowels[2] = "countI";
     vowels[3] = "countO";
     vowels[4] = "countU";

     for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = i + vowels[i] + "<br />";

     }
     // This code will output the results.
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Total Letters: " + arrayOfLetters.length + "<br />";
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "A's: " + countA + "<br />";
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "E's: " + countE + "<br />";
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I's: " + countI + "<br />";
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "O's: " + countO + "<br />";
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "U's: " + countU + "<br />";
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Punctuation: " + countComma + "<br />";
 }
```

This is my HTML.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <h1> Vowel Counter </h1>
    Please enter text for your vowel count:
    <br>
    <textarea id="text" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="countVowels();">Count Vowels</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
```

And this is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt1990/3Ckw2/222/).

Comment: Looks fine... at least the counts seem correct. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What part of the code would you expect to make text bold?

Comment: i want to make it if someone enters text in the text box when the press the count vowels button the most used vowel will come up in bold not the text the counter.

Comment: Than you should write code for it, these things don't happen automagically... You should also output it somehwere else than a textarea.

Comment: Where is the part of code that attempts to make the vowel bold? *"I don't know whether I am missing some code or if I have got something wrong in my code"* - what? is this your code or what? You don't even know whether you've attempted to make it bold or not?

Comment: thats what i dont know what i have done wrong i have tryed a couple of things but i dont know what sort of code i have to use im a bit stuck on that.

Comment: i have tried to it is my code i dont need to steal other peoples code im not stupid to use other peoples code

Comment: i had this in there before for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = i + vowels[i] + "<br />";
        if (vowels == ){
            countA => countE = bold;

Comment: If you're asking why is this code not working, Then you should share your attempt. If you remove the non-working attempt and ask what's wrong sharing the rest of the code, how can someone answer it? answer will be "you should write code for that first". else you should ask something like *"How can i make text inside a `<textarea>` bold"*.

Comment: so thats why i dont know where i have gone wrong and thats why i need help i have tried to get it to work i have been stuck for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be getting the count right. So the only problems left I guess are:

1. Getting max count
2. Displaying it in bold

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values) to get max count, and then some tweaks to your code to get the max count displayed in bold.

```
var vowels = new Array ();
vowels [0] = {"vowel" : "A", "count" : countA};
vowels [1] = {"vowel" : "E", "count" : countE};
vowels [2] = {"vowel" : "I", "count" : countI};
vowels [3] = {"vowel" : "O", "count" : countO};
vowels [4] = {"vowel" : "U", "count" : countU};
var maxCount = Math.max.apply(Math, vowels.map(function(o) {
    return o.count;
}));

for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += (vowels[i].count == maxCount? "<B>" : "") + vowels[i].vowel + "'s: " + vowels[i].count + "<br />";
}
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ckw2/226/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < text.length ; i++){
 if(text[i] == vowelsmustusedUpCase || text[i] == vowelsmustusedLowCase ){
  result += "<strong>"+text[i]+"</strong>";
 } else {
  result += text[i];
 }
} 
document.getElementById("text").value = result ;
```

add this, but in textarea you can't see the bold

Comment: i dont need text area bold but the result bold does it work for that

Comment: it doesnt work i tried nothing comes up at all. @Carbos

Comment: insert it in the function and specify the vowels must used in: `vowelsmustusedUpCase` and `vowelsmustusedLowCase` and change the: `document.getElementById("text").value = result ;` if you want it in another div

Comment: what should i change it to though

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's a code review/answer:

First I modified these lines:

```
var countA = text.match(/[Aa]/g).length;
```

To:

```
var countA = (text.match(/[Aa]/g) ? text.match(/[Aa]/g).length : 0);
```

As it returns "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null*" if the vowel doesn't appear in the control. This will set's it to 0.

Next I simplified the array declaration to:

```
var vowels = ["countA", "countE", "countI", "countO", "countU"];
```

Then I removed this seciton, which does nothing as it's overwritten later:

```
// does nothing
//    for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
//       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = i + vowels[i] + "<br />";
//    }
```

Then I worked out the highest count using `Math.max`:

```
var maxVal = Math.max(countA,countE,countI,countO,countU);
```

Then to make the value bold in the output, I created a function to compare values to the max value:

```
function formatValue(val, max) {
    return (val === max) ? '<strong>' + val + '</strong>' : val;
}
```

So your final section would call this function to output the number like this:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "A's: " + formatValue(countA,maxVal) + "<br />";
```

### [Demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mowsj4r/)

### Complete JS

```
function countVowels() {

    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var arrayOfLetters = text.split("");

    // These are the counters for the program to find the vowels.
    var countA = (text.match(/[Aa]/g) ? text.match(/[Aa]/g).length : 0);
    var countE = (text.match(/[Ee]/g) ? text.match(/[Ee]/g).length : 0);
    var countI = (text.match(/[Ii]/g) ? text.match(/[Ii]/g).length : 0);
    var countO = (text.match(/[Oo]/g) ? text.match(/[Oo]/g).length : 0);
    var countU = (text.match(/[Uu]/g) ? text.match(/[Uu]/g).length : 0);
    var countComma = (text.match(/[,.!": ;?)(]/gi) ? text.match(/[,.!": ;?)(]/gi).length : 0);

    var bold = "<strong>";
    var vowels = ["countA", "countE", "countI", "countO", "countU"];       
    var maxVal = Math.max(countA,countE,countI,countO,countU);

    // This code will output the results.
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Total Letters: " + arrayOfLetters.length + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "A's: " + formatValue(countA,maxVal) + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "E's: " + formatValue(countE,maxVal) + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I's: " + formatValue(countI,maxVal) + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "O's: " + formatValue(countO,maxVal) + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "U's: " + formatValue(countU,maxVal) + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Punctuation: " + countComma + "<br />";
}

function formatValue(val, max) {
    return (val === max) ? '<strong>' + val + '</strong>' : val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first find which is the most used vowel, and then compare it with the result line in your output. E.g.:

```
vowelCount = { A: countA, E: countE, I: countI, O:countO, U:countU };

// Find vowel with maximum appearances
var vowelMaxCount = -1;
var vowelMostPopular = -1;
for(vowel in vowelCount) {
    if(vowelCount[vowel] > vowelMaxCount) {
        vowelMaxCount = vowelCount[vowel];
        vowelMostPopular = vowel;
    }
}

// This code will output the results.
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Total Letters: " + arrayOfLetters.length + "<br />";
for(vowel in vowelCount) {
    v = (vowel == vowelMostPopular)?"<strong>"+vowel+"</strong>":vowel;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += v+"'s: " + vowelCount[vowel] + "<br />";
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Punctuation: " + countComma + "<br />";
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/a8n947kw/1/