# Alternative to d3.max and d3.min functions

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using **dashing-js** and trying to do the following

```
var d3 = require('d3');
```

Whitout success and I don't get any error messages more than that my jobs aren't running at all.

Any way I'm only want to make use of the **d3.max** and **d3.min** functions. Do anyOne of you perhaps know where I could find the javascript implementation of those 2 functions so I can just cop n paste them at the bottom of my js job file and don't have to import d3 at all?

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: So you have an array and you want the max and min values within the array? This question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1669190/4026797 should have an answer for you -- Possible duplicate, but I guess there's no "selected answer." This answer in particular looks promising http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669222/4026797.

Comment: if you're using underscore/lodash they also have min/max implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the minimum value of an array `arr`:

```
Math.min.apply(this,arr);
```

Similary, for maximum value

```
Math.max.apply(this,arr);
```

You don't need a library or even a function.