# Collect outerHeights of div-elements, store them in an array and identify the highest number.

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I want to collect three numbers and then identify the highest number. The numbers are the outer heights of div-elements. I tried to store the outer heights in an array but unfortunately I don't know how to do so. This is how I started:

```
$ var heights = [];

$('.elements').each(function(i){
   $(this).outerHeight(trainingshoehen[i]);
});
```

But it does not work. How can I write these numbers into an array and in the second step how can I compare these numbers best?

Would be nice to get any tips! Thnak you.

Comment: [var max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, array);](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6102340/958375) Will work to find the max of a small data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  It will get the outerHeights of the elements and push them to the heights array.

```
var heights = [];

$('.elements').each(function(i){
    heights.push($(this).outerHeight())
}); 

var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);
```

Comment: `outerHeight` is a jQuery `function`. Use `$(this).outerHeight()` inside the push.

Comment: Yes. this is what I am looking for :) 
@Martin Yes, outerHeight is a function. With "`()`" I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". And without "`()`" the values are undefined…

Comment: @MartinErnst Thanks, change made.

Comment: @iMax Then you've lost one dollar (before `(this)`).