# Find max value in a sparse javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, max, undefined

Is there a proper way to find the max value of a sparse array with undefined values?

Thanks

```
var testArr=[undefined,undefined,undefined,3,4,5,6,7];
console.log('max value with undefined is ',(Math.max.apply(null,testArr)));

// max value with undefined is NaN

console.log('max with arr.max()',testArr.max());    

// Error: testArr.max is not a function     

testArr=[null,null,null,3,4,5,6,7];
console.log('max value with null is ',(Math.max.apply(null,testArr)));

// max value with null is 7
```

I'd prefer not to do forEach if there is a built-in method.

Comment: forEach is a built-in method

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: @DanielWeiner a built-in method *of finding the max value*

Comment: `Math.max` attempts to convert its arguments to numbers. Since `undefined` is converted to `NaN` (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) it will fail with those values. You'll have to iterate over the values. The closest thing to "built-in" is `Array.reduce`.

Comment: Also, `null` is converted to 0 so you'll get the wrong answer if your array is filled with `null`s and negative numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
testArr.reduce(function(a,b){
  if (isNaN(a) || a === null || a === '') a = -Infinity;
  if (isNaN(b) || b === null || b === '') b = -Infinity;
  return Math.max(a,b)
}, -Infinity);
```

Comment: Empty strings with negative numbers would be an issue as it stands.

Comment: Good catch, I just updated my solution to account for empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

None of your examples are true sparse arrays (they don't have any 'holes'), but you could use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (ECMA5) to test the value [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite). For better accuracy ECMA6 will offer [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite). Remember there are also limits to the number of arguments that [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) can handle (often 65536 arguments). Of course, [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) may not be suitable for your application, if you want `Infinity` and `-Infinity`, then you should use a different test. An empty string with negative numbers would be an issue in this current exampe.

```js
var testArr = [undefined, , , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

document.body.textContent = Math.max.apply(null, testArr.filter(function (x) {
    return isFinite(x);
}));
```

Comment: Simply `testArr.filter(isFinite)`

Comment: @georg Yes indeed, I was thinking that having it verbose may be better for the answer as it is not clear that `isFinite` is the best check for the question raised.