# Find min and max value for dateaxis in jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I am using dateaxis render for my x-axis. How can I find the min and max value from the x-axis valuse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: You mean min max from your series dataset? Or min max tick label value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the minimum/maximum x-axis value from your dataset you can use:

```
plot1.axes.xaxis._dataBounds.min
```

If you want the minimum/maximum from the x-axis (i.e. tick label) you can use:

```
plot1.axes.xaxis.min
```

where plot1 is a reference to the jqplot object. These return the minimum/maximum dates in milliseconds.

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dH7Hm/106/) for an example. The 2 buttons can be used to display the min or max values.