# Find maximum variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, max

I have thirty variables which are all numbers:

h0 = 23

h1 = 27

h2 = 90

...

How do I find the largest variable?

The output here should be h2.

Comment: Instead of using variables, use an array and follow [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1669190/218196).

Comment: Please note: I want the output to be "h2" and not "90"

Comment: Do you have them just as plain vars or in an object?

Comment: Then what you want is not possible in plain Javascript, you do not have access to variable names at runtime.

Comment: I guess the big question is, why do you want the variable name?

Comment: It is possible, but only if the names of your variables always have the index in them but you should be using an array.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the variables are all named in consecutive order, you can add them to an array:

```
var values = [h0, h1, ....h29];
```

Then iterate over the array, compare the values and keep track of the index of the max value:

```
var maxIndex = 0;

for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
   if (values[maxIndex] < values[i]) {
       maxIndex = i;
   }
}
```

`maxIndex` will now contain the index of the maximum value, and you could concat it with `'h'`, e.g.

```
console.log('h' + maxIndex);
```

Of course this approach makes a lot of assumptions and is fragile, but that's what you get when doing this kind of "meta-programming" (the *variable name* really should not be of any concern to anybody using the app).

---

Using an object would make it a bit better, at least concerning the variable name:

```
var values = {
    h0: h0,
    h1: h1,
    ...
};

var maxProp = '';

for (var prop in values) {
   if (values[maxProp] < values[prop]) {
       maxProp = prop;
   }
}
```

Comment: The first solution does not work for me:
h0=5; 
h1=2;
h2=7;
h3=9;
h4=1;
values = [h0,h1,h2,h3,h4]

var maxIndex = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
   if (values[maxIndex] < values[i]) {
       maxIndex = i;
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

Put them in an array instead of individual variables, then loop over the array.

To brute-force it, compare adjacent pairs of variables, then pairs of the results, until only one is left.

Comment: Is this the only way? Seems strange that no simpler way exists

Comment: Well, tell me what you expect to do without using a data structure.

Comment: I have no idea, I am a beginner. I would be grateful if you could explain how to use a data structure. If that is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the answer to be 'h2' instead of '90' (per comment), try using an Object instead of separate variables (or an array, as mentioned in other answers).

```
var find_max = {
  'h0': 23,
  'h1': 27,
  'h2': 90,
  // and so on
};
```

Then loop over the properties of the object to find the maximum.

```
var max;
for (var h in find_max) {
  if (!max || (find_max[h] > find_max[max])) {
    max = h;
  }
}
```

You can probably improve this loop - try using `hasOwnProperty` to make sure that the only items in the loop are the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it easily by checking the window object using [the bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) this way:

```js
h0 = 11;
h1 = 24;
h2 = 28;
h3 = 345;
h4 = 1;

var i = 0;
var max = {
    name: 'none',
    val: 0
};
while (nextItem = window['h'+i]) {
    if (nextItem > max.val) {
        max = {
            name: 'h'+i,
            val: nextItem
        };
    };
    i++;
};
document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = max.name + ' = ' + max.val;
```

```html
<p>Maximum is: <span id="max"></span></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

*EDIT:* I was too hasty in posting the below as it didn't take into account the real question.  Since then there have been good answers presented so I'll just show a way that you can sort the variables in descending order.  One way would be to place the numbers in an array of objects such that:

```
numArray = [{name:h0, value:23}, {name:h1, value:27}, {name:h2, value:90}];
```

And do:

```
numArray.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.value - a.value;
});
```

---

According to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

It looks pretty easy once you have the numbers in an array.  You could call

```
Math.max.apply(null, numArray)
```

on the array, or, using ES6, you could say Math.max(...numArray) (... is the "spread" operator).

You could also do a sort:

```
 numArray.sort(function(a, b){
      return b - a;
   });
```

Which would sort your array in descending order with the maximum number now at numArray[0].