# JavaScript finding the largest integer in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var newArray = [];
    for(var i =0; i <=arr.length-1; i++){
        console.log(arr[i]);
        newArray[i] = Math.max(arr[i]);
    }
    console.log(newArray);
              // You can do this!
    return newArray;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

So I do not understand why I am getting `NaN` even though i have provided an argument within my `math.max` function. In the console.log within my for loop, i get each array within the main array to display. Meaning if I use the same `arr[i]` within the max function, it should give me the max of that sub Array.

Comment: Do you want to find the largest in the arrays?

Comment: yes So what i am trying to accomplish is go through each subarray and find the max integer within it, and pass the max integer into a seperate array. So the function return an array with 4 integers each integer being the max integer of the 4 sub array within the main array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why math.max() returning NaN with array of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647149/why-math-max-returning-nan-with-array-of-integers)

Answer (score 3):

You are passing an array to `Math.max` and expect it to return the maximum in that array.

However, `Math.max` returns the maximum among its arguments. So use

```
var newArray = [];
for(var i =0; i < arr.length; ++i)
  newArray[i] = Math.max.apply(void 0, arr[i]);
```

In ES6, you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to simplify:

```
arr.map(a => Math.max(...a));
```

Comment: Cool! Your solution works however before I use it, i want to know what does the void 0 mean within math.max.apply()?

Comment: @AliAslam It's the value used as the `this` value inside the function. Since `Math.max` doesn't use it, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Or just `newArray = arr.map(Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, Math))` :)

Answer (score 2):

It won't work like that. `Math.max` expect separate numbers. You can get desired output using `apply`

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(subArr){
        return Math.max.apply(Math, subArr);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ultimate max do this.

```
var original = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];
Math.max.apply(null, original.map(function(arr) { return Math.max.apply(null, arr); }));
```

or if you want a the max of each array just do

```
original.map(function(arr) { return Math.max.apply(null, arr); });
```

Comment: So this actually returns a single max among all arrays which is not the OP's intent. But can be a separate task

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash

```
var x = ([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
_.flatten(x).max();
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited:
In order to add values to the array, I'd suggest using the push methodn.  As in:
NewArray.push(Math.max(...sub[i])); or newarray.push(math.max.apply(null, sub[i]).
An alternative is alocating, when declarating the array, the size it will take:
Var newArray = new Array(arr.length);
There's this new spread operator (...) in javascript !

Comment: `Math.max([1,2,3])` doesn't find the max aomng array elements. It returns `NaN`.

Comment: Yes! In fact, i've done a better research and Math.max only accepts numbers, not the array. If you pass sub[i] you will have the NaN. I suggest newarray.push(null, math.max.apply(sub[i]))

Comment: There is no spread operator (`...`) in widely available javascript, i.e. in browsers. As mentioned in other answers it is a feature of ES6