# How to get the highest value in a json format dataset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using highcharts, which uses a data series to plot the chart similar to this:

series:

```
[{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

I know that I can use a Json file to feed the dataset so, how can I get its highest value?

Comment: Unable to understand the question.

Comment: are you looking for JavaScript to get the [maximum value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values) of the array you've posted? There's already an answer for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get the highest value in the data array.

```
data = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

var highest_value = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
console.log(highest_value) //216.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is JSON, you need to parse it first:

```
var dataset = JSON.parse(rawDataset);
```

Then you can use the `Math.max` function with the array applied as the arguments to filter the largest value:

```
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, dataset[0].data);
```