# How can I properly use jQuery to fix this fencepost case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, optimization, responsive-design

I have a function

```
function giveTheseEqualHeight ( selector )
{
     // selector: CSS selector of elements on the page to be forced to have the same height

     var these = $(selector);
     if (these.length < 2) return; 
     these.height('auto');
     var maxHeight = these.first().height();
     these.each(function(){
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if (thisHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = thisHeight;                
     });
     these.height(maxHeight);
}
```

which is very self explanatory.

Example use case:

```
giveTheseEqualHeight('.service-column h3');
```

would make all `h3` elements that are descendants of elements of class `service-column` have equal height by heightening the ones that are smaller than the one with the most height.

The problem is that the loop

```
             these.each(function(){
                var thisHeight = $(this).height();
                if (thisHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = thisHeight;                
             });
```

doesn't need to execute its body on the first iteration -- such amounts to useless operations. Instead of `these.each`, I want to start with the 2nd item. Is this possible?

Comment: It's not repeated work if you initialize maxHeight to zero :)

Comment: @dtanders Good point!

Comment: I wouldn't waste my time on this micro-optimization.

Comment: @Barmar PIP'n ain't easy :(

Comment: @dtanders Don't make fun of my username. It's no laughing matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid calculating height of the first element if you get array of heights and then take the max with native Math.max:

```
function giveTheseEqualHeight(selector) {
    var these = $(selector);
    if (these.length < 2) return;
    these.height('auto');

    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, these.map(function(el) {
        return $(this).height();
    }));
    these.height(maxHeight);
}
```

Here is a demo of it:

```js
function giveTheseEqualHeight(selector) {
    var these = $(selector);
    if (these.length < 2) return;
    these.height('auto');
    
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, these.map(function(el) {
     return $(this).height();
    }));
    these.height(maxHeight);
}

giveTheseEqualHeight('div')
```

```css
div {display: inline-block;background: #EEE; vertical-align: top;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Lorem</div>
<div>Test <br>rest</div>
<div>Test <br> and rest <br>on the <br>west</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's faster? Getting an array of the heights involves iterating through the elements. So that's an extra iteration through an object of length `N`.

Comment: If you are really concerned with performance then don't use jQuery each in the first place, go with native loop and compare like you are doing now.

Comment: @WebDevonPIPatAmazon.com if you're really concerned about speed, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13440842/1770430 has a solution that's purported to be 3X faster than Math.max.apply().

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has `slice`. Slice from second element (index 1). If the end is omitted, it slices until the end.

```
these.slice(1).each(...);
```

Comment: Does `slice` use references of the set of returned objects, or does it make copies of them?

Comment: @WebDevonPIPatAmazon.com The contents are the same references. It's just the wrapping jQuery object that's different.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `greater-than` selector to select all elements who's index is greater than the number provided.

- http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/