# How do Javascript Math.max and Math.min actually work?

Tags: javascript, math

I am really curious how these functions actually work? I know there are a lot of questions about how to use these, I already know how to use them, but I couldn't find anywhere how to actually go about implementing this functionality on an array, for example, if there were no such functions? How would you code such a function if there were no helpers?

Comment: Initialize a value; iterate over the collection, testing if each element is greater or lesser than the current highest/lowest value; if so, replace the value with that element.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the Math.max code in Chrome V8 engine.

```
function MathMax(arg1, arg2) {  // length == 2
  var length = %_ArgumentsLength();
  if (length == 2) {
    arg1 = TO_NUMBER(arg1);
    arg2 = TO_NUMBER(arg2);
    if (arg2 > arg1) return arg2;
    if (arg1 > arg2) return arg1;
    if (arg1 == arg2) {
      // Make sure -0 is considered less than +0.
      return (arg1 === 0 && %_IsMinusZero(arg1)) ? arg2 : arg1;
    }
    // All comparisons failed, one of the arguments must be NaN.
    return NaN;
  }
  var r = -INFINITY;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var n = %_Arguments(i);
    n = TO_NUMBER(n);
    // Make sure +0 is considered greater than -0.
    if (NUMBER_IS_NAN(n) || n > r || (r === 0 && n === 0 && %_IsMinusZero(r))) {
      r = n;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/cd81dd6d740ff82a1abbc68615e8769bd467f91e/src/js/math.js#L77-L102) is the repository.

Comment: Actually, [it's in JavaScript](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/cd81dd6d740ff82a1abbc68615e8769bd467f91e/src/js/math.js#L77-L102).

Answer (score 7):

Below is how to implement the functions if `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` did *not* exist.

Functions have an **[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)** object, which you can iterate through to get its values.

It's important to note that **[`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)** with no arguments returns `Infinity`, and **[`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)** with no arguments returns `-Infinity`.

```js
function min() {
  var result= Infinity;
  for(var i in arguments) {
    if(arguments[i] < result) {
      result = arguments[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function max() {
  var result= -Infinity;
  for(var i in arguments) {
    if(arguments[i] > result) {
      result = arguments[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//Tests
console.log(min(5,3,-2,4,14));       //-2
console.log(Math.min(5,3,-2,4,14));  //-2

console.log(max(5,3,-2,4,14));       //14
console.log(Math.max(5,3,-2,4,14));  //14

console.log(min());                  //Infinity
console.log(Math.min());             //Infinity

console.log(max());                  //-Infinity
console.log(Math.max());             //-Infinity
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a look at the specifications (which could/should help you in implementation!)

In [ECMAScript 1st Edition (ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) (the initial definitions for both Math.max/min), we see the following:

```
15.8.2.11 max(x, y)
Returns the larger of the two arguments.
    • If either argument is NaN, the result is NaN.
    • If x>y, the result is x.
    • If y>x, the result is y.
    • If x is +0 and y is +0, the result is +0.
    • If x is +0 and y is −0, the result is +0.
    • If x is −0 and y is +0, the result is +0.
    • If x is −0 and y is −0, the result is −0.

15.8.2.12 min(x, y)
    Returns the smaller of the two arguments.
    • If either argument is NaN, the result is NaN.
    • If x<y, the result is x.
    • If y<x, the result is y.
    • If x is +0 and y is +0, the result is +0.
    • If x is +0 and y is −0, the result is −0.
    • If x is −0 and y is +0, the result is −0.
    • If x is −0 and y is −0, the result is −0.
```

Later versions of the specification give us:

[ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.11)

```
15.8.2.11 max ( [ value1 [ , value2 [ , … ] ] ] )

    Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the largest of the resulting values.

    • If no arguments are given, the result is −∞.
    • If any value is NaN, the result is NaN.
    • The comparison of values to determine the largest value is done as in 11.8.5 except that +0 is considered to be larger than −0.

    The length property of the max method is 2.

15.8.2.12 min ( [ value1 [ , value2 [ , … ] ] ] )

    Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the smallest of the resulting values.

    • If no arguments are given, the result is +∞.
    • If any value is NaN, the result is NaN.
    • The comparison of values to determine the smallest value is done as in 11.8.5 except that +0 is considered to be larger than −0.

    The length property of the min method is 2.
```

The reference to 11.8.5 can be found here: [The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5)

[ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.max)

```
20.2.2.24 Math.max ( value1, value2 , …values )

    Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the largest of the resulting values.

    • If no arguments are given, the result is −∞.
    • If any value is NaN, the result is NaN.
    • The comparison of values to determine the largest value is done using the Abstract Relational Comparison algorithm (7.2.11) except that +0 is considered to be larger than −0.

    The length property of the max method is 2.

20.2.2.25 Math.min ( value1, value2 , …values )

    Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the smallest of the resulting values.

    • If no arguments are given, the result is +∞.
    • If any value is NaN, the result is NaN.
    • The comparison of values to determine the smallest value is done using the Abstract Relational Comparison algorithm (7.2.11) except that +0 is considered to be larger than −0.

The length property of the min method is 2.
```

And again, 7.2.11 can be found here: [Abstract Relational Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison)

Answer (score 3):

**Basic functionality:**

Math.max() and Math.min() are used on numbers (or what they can coerce into numbers) you cannot directly pass an array as a parameter.

Ex:

```
Math.max(1,52,28)
```

You can have an number of comma delimited numbers.

**Arrays:**

This example shows how one could apply them to arrays:

[JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

**Basically** the following works:

```
Math.max.apply(null, [1,5,2,3]);
```

**Why that works?**

This works because apply is a function that all functions have which applies a function with the arguments of an array.

Math.max.apply(null, [1,5,2,3]) is the same as Math.max(1,5,2,3)

Comment: Don't forget, it also works on Objects that have the same properties as an array : `Math.max.apply(null,{0:1,1:4,2:2,length:3})`

Comment: @ahitt6345 That's a good point; and that could be helpful.  of course you'd have to do Math.functionname.apply(null,obj);  I just wanted to point that out in case someone wondered why exactly copying that didn't work.

Comment: whoops, forgot about the function i wanted to apply... thanks for telling me. :| lol

Comment: *Math.max() and Math.min() are used on numbers.* But they will also coerce their parameters if not numbers.

Comment: in ES6 you can use the spread operator `Math.max(...array)`, but note that there is a maximum number of arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834687/106623

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's `min` without `Math.min` (code is in ES6).

```
function min() {
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce(
    (minSoFar, next) => minSoFar < next ? minSoFar : next
  , Infinity)
}
```

The same logic could be implemented with a simple loop. You would just need to keep track of one of variable through your iteration, which is the lowest value you've seen so far. The initial value of `minSoFar` would be `Infinity`. The reason is that *any* Number except `Infinity` is less than `Infinity`, but in the case of *no* arguments sent, we want to return `Infinity` itself, because that's what `Math.min()` with no arguments evaluates to.

```
function min() {
  let minSoFar = Infinity
  for(let i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) {
    const next = arguments[i]
    minSoFar = minSoFar < next ? minSoFar : next
  }
  return minSoFar
}
```

`Max` can be implemented with pretty much the same logic, only you're keeping track of the highest value you've seen so far, and the initial value is `-Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to implement with `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
function min() {
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

   var minValue = args.reduce(function(currentMin, nextNum) {
      if (nextNum < currentMin) {
         // nextNum is less than currentMin, so we return num
         // which will replace currentMin with nextNum
         return nextNum;
      }
      else {
         return currentMin;
      }
   }, Infinity);

   return minValue;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to slice first; you can just do `Array.prototype.reduce.call`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation of **Math.min** and **Math.max** from a real Javascript engine

**Math.max** : https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/cd81dd6d740ff82a1abbc68615e8769bd467f91e/src/js/math.js#L78-L102

**Math.min** : https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/cd81dd6d740ff82a1abbc68615e8769bd467f91e/src/js/math.js#L105-L129