# getLargestExpressionResult(a,b)

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return

I'm trying to get this function done but something is wrong, it should return 50 for a=5,b=10 or 2  for a=1,b=1. However any other way to write this function would be interesting

```js
function getLargestExpressionResult(a, b) {
  const sum = a + b;
  const prod = a * b;
  const diff = a - b;
  const quot = a \ b;
  
  let res = sum;
  
  if (prod > res) res = prod;
  if (diff > res) res = diff;
  if (quot > res) res = quot;
  
  return res;
}
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: you need to take `/` instead of backslash `\\\`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.max()`. It can take multiple parameters and gives you max.
Also for division it is `/`

```js
function getLargestExpressionResult(a, b) {
  const sum = a + b;
  const prod = a * b;
  const diff = a - b;
  const quot = a / b;
  
  return Math.max(sum,prod,diff,quot);
}

console.log(getLargestExpressionResult(5, 10))
```

Comment: the purpose of this was to make it  working without using Math

Comment: then just change the \ to /. your one is fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851810/how-do-javascript-math-max-and-math-min-actually-work

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to find maximum element on your own, you can simply use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```js
const getLargestExpressionResult = (a, b) => Math.max(a * b, a / b, a + b, a - b);

console.log(getLargestExpressionResult(5, 10));
console.log(getLargestExpressionResult(1, 1));
```

Also should be noticed division is `/`, not `\`.

Or if you need to avoid [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) usage:

```js
getLargestExpressionResult = (a, b) => {
    const expressionValues = [ a + b, a - b, a * b, a / b ];
    let max = expressionValues[0];
    for (const value of expressionValues) {
        if (value > max) max = value;
    }
    return max;
}

console.log(getLargestExpressionResult(5, 10));
console.log(getLargestExpressionResult(1, 1));
```