# Grab Higher Value base on a Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an array `$array = [5,10,15,20,25];` and a value.

Let's say my value is `23`, then I want to grab `25` because `25` is the next higher value.

---

I've tried in PHP

```
public static function findHigherValue($val,$arr){
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if( $value <= $val){
            $higher = $value;
        }
    }

    return $higher;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: @MinusFour : I'm not looking for a Min / Max value of an array.

Comment: If the current value is 13, I want to grab 15.

Comment: If the value is 39, I want to grab 40. Get it ? How is it the same as min/max ? Please kindly unmark my question. I can improve it - if I missed anything.

Comment: @NinaScholz : I'm updating my post. Give me a couple mins.

Comment: Then you are trying to get the closest highest number to the value...

Answer (score 1):

If this is javascript, the following script should solve your problem:

```
var $result = $array.reduce(function(a,b) { return a >= $value && a-$value < b-$value : a : b }, Infinity);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confident one of the newer array methods would do this faster but I'd loop through

```
function getClosestIndex(arr, value){
   var smallestDelta = Infinity;
   var index;
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       //subtract the array value from the give value
       var delta = Math.abs(arr[i] - value);
       if(delta < smallestDelta){
          smallestDelta = delta;
          index = i;
       }
   }
   return index;
}

var output = getClosestIndex($array, 13);
$array[output]; //should return the closest value
```

EDIT: I see the question has changed. It looks like you want closest value in the array.  I've edited the code above for that.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a javascript question, and you know the array is sorted:

```
var currentValue = 13;
array.find(function (value) {
    return value >= currentValue;
})
```

`find` is not supported in IE though (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var array = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40];
var input = 10;
var value = array.filter(function(item) {
  return item > input;
}).sort()[0];
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = value;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution gives the same or the next higher value from the pattern array. It works for sorted arrays only.

```js
var pattern = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40],
    given = [1, 13, 27, 39],
    i = 0,
    result = given.map(function (a) {
        while (pattern[i] < a) {
            i++;
        }
        return pattern[i];
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Array.sort() function can give unexpected results due to Unicode - See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Would it be a good idea to run over the array using a for loop and use a simple comparitor against the previous values?

```
$array = [5,10,45,15,20,25,30,35,40];

var num = $array[0]; // Your first comparitor
var highest;
for (i=0; i<$array.length; i++) {
    console.log(highest);
    if($array[i] > num) {
        num = $array[i];
        highest = $array[i];
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Rolos

Answer (score 1):

Another option using PHP, use `array_filter` to remove the lower value from `$value` and get the min value afterwards.

```
$value = 25;

$array = array_filter($array, function ($x) use ($value) { return $x > $value; })

echo min($array);
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the value is 13 as example, OP then wants 15 and not 10.

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123, made some mistakes there. Corrected. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

This returns the closest number that is higher or equal than the search value:

```js
function findClosest(arr, val){
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, el){
    if(el >= val){
      if(acc === null) return el;
      var d1 = el - val,
          d2 = Math.abs(acc - val);
      return d1 < d2 ? el : acc;
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
  }, null);
}

console.log(findClosest([5,16,20,20,25,10,5,30], 16));
```

Sorted, unsorted, repeated values, etc. Shouldn't affect the outcome.

**Edit**: I figured `0` isn't the best value to return when there's no match. So I rewrited it a bit. This will return `null` if no match is found.