# turning a for loop and a while loop into a do...while loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, do-while

I have these 2 loops to find the highest number in an integer array (a for loop and a while loop that serve the same purpose)
For:

```
var forHighest = function(array) {
  var highest = array[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (highest < array[i]) {
      highest = array[i];
    }
  }
  return highest;
};
```

While:

```
var whileHighest = function(array) {
  var i = 0;
  var highest = array[0];
  while (i < array.length) {
    if (array[i] > highest)
      highest = array[i];
    i++;
  }
  return highest;
};
```

But now I need to make a While loop but everything I try keeps giving me the number at the [0] index of my array. I don't think I've ever used a do...while loop functionally before so maybe I'm not understanding fully how they work. Here are a few of my attempts:

```
var doWhile = function(array) {
  var i = 0;
  do {
    i++;
  } while (i < array.length);
  if (array[i] > highest)
    highest = array[i];
  return highest;
};
```

also:

```
var i = 0;
var highest = array[0];
do{
    if(highest < array[i]){
    highest = array[i];
    i++;
    } 
  } while(i < array.length);
```

and:

```
var doWhile = function(array) {
    var i = [i];
//  var i = 0;
    var highest = array[i];
    do
      {
       i++;
      } while (array[i] < highest && i < array.length);
        //  if (array[i] > highest);
        return array[i];
```

But none of them work. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your first do while is completely pointless (does nothing in the loop except increment i) - your second loop will loop forever, because you need to do i++ OUTSIDE the if condition, your third loop makes `i` an array, so, wont work at all ... you're close though ... move the i++ in the second do..while outside the if condition, and you should be golden

Comment: If your purpose is to find max and min then you can take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values

Comment: @sinto - arrays do not have a max/min function (yet?)

Comment: @Jaromanda X-sorry about that comment:var arr = [10,0,30,40];
arr.max = function() { return  Math.max.apply(Math, this); };
arr.min = function() { return  Math.min.apply(Math, this); }; 
alert("min: " + arr.min() + " max: " + arr.max());

Comment: @sinto, no need to apologise, the arr.min/arr.max code is more clear in the link provided in the comment by user2181397 anyway ... but, I don't think this question is really about getting the min/max of an array

Answer (score 1):

First up, understand that the `do-while` loop is not much different than the `while` loop. The only difference is that `do-while` is an exit testing loop, whereas the `while` loop is an entry testing loop.

So, in the `do-while` the looping criteria i.e., the condition in the `while` parentheses, is evaluated while exiting the loop. And in order to do exit the loop, it has to enter the loop at least once. Hence, the assured at-least-one-time-run of the block of code in the do-while loop. Other than that the way the `while` loop works is same as the `do-while`. Same initialization code. Bringing about the exit criteria inside the loop also remains the same.

Now looking at your code, your while loop (shown below) works fine:

```
while (i < array.length) {
    if (array[i] > highest)
      highest = array[i];
    i++;
  }
```

Now, we can rewrite it as the `do-while` by simply moving the `while` statement to the end and put the `do` in its place. Note that the code before the loop (that is, the pre-looping initialization code) needs no change, either.

That is,

```
var i = 0;
var highest = array[0];
do {
    if (array[i] > highest)
      highest = array[i];
    i++;
  } while (i < array.length);
return highest;
```

As mentioned by @Jaromanda X in the comment, you should be golden :)

Comment: well done explaining the difference between `while` and `do...while`

Comment: yes, Thank You so much @SarathChandra - you actually rlly explained this so much better than any of the resources I found online- Thank you so much! I rlly appreciate it!

Comment: @H.Hirschfeld : Glad I could help!!

Answer (score 1):

> As mentioned in the comments, there are better ways to  get the max/min in an array, but the point of the question is to know how write a `do...while` loop

Your second do...while was close

```
var i = 0;
var highest = array[0];
do {
    if (highest < array[i]){
        highest = array[i];
    }
    i++;  // this line moved out of the if block
} while(i < array.length);
```

However, more correctly

```
var i = 1;
var highest = array[0];
if (array.length > 1) {
    do {
        if(highest < array[i]){
            highest = array[i];
        }
        i++;  
    } while(i < array.length);
}
```

because there's no need to check if the array is a single element, nor do you need to check array[0] against array[0], so you can start the loop with i = 1

Comment: And, thank you too @Jaromanda X - this has rlly cleared up do..while loops for me & some of the details! Thanks, I really appreciate it!