# Largest array I can safely pass to function.apply() / spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays

The "JavaScriptonic" way to [calculate the maximum value of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values) is:

```
Math.max.apply(null, array)
```

However, this errors with "maximum call stack size exceeded" on arrays of size 2^16 (Chrome, Safari) or 2^18 (Firefox). See https://jsfiddle.net/dxcot206/

How can I use this technique safely? Is there a largest array length for which this technique is guaranteed to work?

Might the answer be different in a WebWorker, since background threads often have smaller stack sizes?

Comment: I had checked it. AFAIR it can be like 126K something something items only.

Comment: what do u want to do with this?

Comment: Just separate your data to guaranteed size chunks and calculate each chunks max. then calculate max of chunks max values.

Comment: Turned out to be 125435 tonight...

Comment: _"Largest array I can safely pass to function.apply() / spread operator"_ What is the expected `.length` of the resulting array, or array which is iterated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I use this technique safely?

Not at all.

> Is there a largest array length for which this technique is guaranteed to work?

No, there are no requirements for such things in the spec, all you are seeing are implementation-dependent "*we don't support unreasonably large argument lists above `N`*" restrictions.

> The "JavaScriptonic" way to calculate the maximum value of an array is: `Math.max.apply(null, array)`

It's just short, but not very efficient, and as you have seen might not work. Better use `array.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))`.

Comment: Is reduce applicable to _unreasonably large array_?

Comment: @mortezaT: Yes, it is (otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it). Btw, an unreasonably lengthy `arguments` list might not be an unreasonably large array :-)

Comment: I would do it like `array.reduce((a,b) => a <= b && b || a);` and just because  how it makes `a` look so sexy.

Comment: @Redu your `max` doesn't work if `0` was the largest element in an array full of negative numbers otherwise.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Oh..! 0 is always a problem when you have &&s ans ||s around... gotto be cautious. Good point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's distressing that ES6 would further cement this practice with the new spread operator.

Comment: @Redu: Just do `array.reduce((a, b) => a < b ? b : a)` instead of weird short-circuiting

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a largest array length for which this technique is guaranteed
>   to work? Might the answer be different in a WebWorker, since background threads
>   often have smaller stack sizes?

To help answer your second (2) questions in a particular environment, here's a script you can run that uses a binary search to figure out the answer:

```
(function () {
  // Returns whether or not the action threw an exception.
  function throwsException(action) {
    try {
      action();
    } catch (e) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  // Performs the action for various values between lower and upper and returns
  // the maximum value for the action to return true.
  function findMaxValueForAction(action, lower, upper) {
    var best;

    while (upper - lower > 1) {
      var previousUpper = upper;

      var guess = Math.floor((lower + upper) / 2);
      if (action(guess)) {
        // If the action is successful then the lower needs to be updated to what just succeeded. 
        lower = guess;
        // Is the (successful) lower better than the current best?
        if (best === undefined || lower > best) {
          // If so update the current best.
          best = lower;
        }
      } else {
        // If the action was unsuccessful the new upper bound is 1 less than what we just tried.
        upper = guess - 1;
      }
    }

    return best;
  }

  var maxArraySize = findMaxValueForAction(function (value) {    
    return !throwsException(function () {
      var array = new Array(value);
    });
  }, 0, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);

  var maxArrayApplySize = findMaxValueForAction(function (value) {
    return !throwsException(function () {
      var array = new Array(value);
      Math.max.apply(null, array);
    });
  }, 0, maxArraySize);

  return [
    'Max "value" for "new Array(value)": ' + maxArraySize, 
    'Max "value" for "Math.max.apply(null, new Array(value))": ' + maxArrayApplySize
  ];
})().forEach(function(message) { console.log(message) });
```