# Find the smallest and largest value in an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write an algorithm that finds and smallest and largest value in an array, and the second largest and second smallest.

I tried with the following:

```js
numbers = [2, 4, 9, 2, 0, 16, 24]

var largest = numbers[0];
var smallest = numbers[0];

for (var i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {

  if (numbers[i] > largest) {
    largest = numbers[i];
  } else if (numbers[i] < smallest) {
    smallest = numbers[i];
  }

  console.log(largest);
  console.log(smallest);
}
```

This does not seem to work and just prints out the array...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your logic's fine for finding the largest and smallest numbers – you just need to move the `console.log` statements outside the loop.

Comment: Oh wow, how did I not see that...how embarrassing.  Any suggestions for getting the second largest and the second smallest?

Comment: "Any suggestions for getting the second largest and the second smallest?" --- create a function that would maintain a sorted array of N elements. Then feed it with your `numbers` array.

Comment: @MadCatm2 Use the same algorithm, just use a new array with the same data and remove the largest and smallest from it. Or sort the array and get index `1` and `n-2` (assuming `n-1` is the last element and `0` is the first).

Comment: Oh, but that would just give me my number array sorted from smallest to largest no?  I just need to return one value that is the second smallest...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to sort the array, then return the first two and last two elements.

Using `slice()` prevents the array itself from being sorted:

```js
var numbers = [2, 4, 9, 2, 0, 16, 24];

var sorted = numbers.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});

var smallest = sorted[0],                      
    secondSmallest = sorted[1],                
    secondLargest = sorted[sorted.length - 2], 
    largest  = sorted[sorted.length - 1];

console.log('Smallest: ' + smallest);
console.log('Second Smallest: ' + secondSmallest);
console.log('Second Largest: ' + secondLargest);
console.log('Largest: ' + largest);
```

Answer (score 3):

Move your console.log statements outside of your for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to pass each array element as an argument to [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) or [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

Using this method, you can find the smallest and largest number in an array:

```js
const numbers = [2, 4, 9, 2, 0, 16, 24];

const smallest_number = Math.min(...numbers);
const largest_number = Math.max(...numbers);

console.log('Smallest Value:', smallest_number); // Smallest Value: 0
console.log('Largest Value:', largest_number);   // Largest Value: 24
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const numbers = [2, 4, 9, 2, 0, 16, 24];

//we can use reduce to find the largest and smallest number

const largest = numbers.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) =>
            previousValue > currentValue ? previousValue : currentValue
        );

const smallest = numbers.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) =>
            previousValue < currentValue ? previousValue : currentValue
        );
```

Comment: Please add some description with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Roatin Marth (edited by Mr. Llama) said in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6102340/6074388 ,

You can make the arrays use math.min and math.max like below

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};
```

If this causes any problems you can also use

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, largest),
max = Math.max.apply(null, largest);

var min = Math.min.apply(null, numbers),
max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers);
```

It won't help with finding the second smallest and second largest numbers, but I find this to be a simpler solution for finding the largest and smallest numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [2, 4, 9, 2, 0, 16, 24]
var largest = numbers[0];
var smallest = numbers[0];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    var temp = numbers[i];
    if (temp > largest)
    {
        largest = numbers[i];
    }
    if (temp < smallest)
    {
        smallest = numbers[i];
    }
}
console.log(largest);
console.log(smallest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [2, 4, 9, 2, 0, 16, 24];
var largest = -Infinity;
var smallest = Infinity;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > largest) {
        largest = numbers[i];
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] < smallest) {
        smallest = numbers[i];
    }
}

console.log(largest);
console.log(smallest);
```

Comment: please add a description to your code snippet to explain how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reduce function for this!

```
var numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25, 100, 43];

var max = numbers.reduce((total, value, index, array) => {
    if(index === 0) return array[0];
    return total > value ? total : value;
});
console.log(max);

var min = numbers.reduce((total, value, index, array) => {
    if(index === 0) return array[0];
    return total < value ? total : value;
});
console.log(min);
```

You can learn how the reduce function works [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp). It is really useful when you have to derive a result from all the values of an array.

I'm also using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for less code.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]


const bigandsmallNum = function(){
    const smallNum = Math.min(...arr)
    const largeNum = Math.max(...arr)
    console.log(smallNum,largeNum)

 }
console.log(bigandsmallNum())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to return an object with largest and smallest:

```
const array = [22, 3, 56 , 7, 14, 100, 2, 44]

const findLargestAndSmallest = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc = acc.largest > cur ? 
   {...acc, largest: acc.largest} : 
   {...acc, largest: cur}
  acc = acc.smallest < cur ? 
   {...acc, smallest: acc.smallest} :
   {...acc, smallest: cur}
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(findLargestAndSmallest(array)) // { largest: 100, smallest: 2 }

// or destruct it: 

const {largest, smallest} = findLargestAndSmallest(array)
console.log(largest) // 100
console.log(smallest) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

const x = [1,2,3,4];

const y = Math.min(...x);

const z =Math.max(...x)

Answer (score 0):

**How you can get the first and second largest number in array** **I hope this would be helpful for everyone thanks**

```js
// first method

const getLargestNumber = (nums) => {
    let largest = [0];
    for (let i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) {
      if (largest <= nums[i]) {
        largest = nums[i]
      }
    }
    return largest;
}

const array = [0, 2, 3, 6, 6, 5]

console.log("first method", getLargestNumber(array))

// second method

const maxNumber = Math.max(...array);

console.log("Second Method", maxNumber)

// third method

const getMaxNumber = array.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0]

console.log("Third Method", getMaxNumber)
```

```js
const getSecondLargest = (nums) => {
    let largest = Math.max(...nums), newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) {
      if ((nums[i] !== undefined) && !(largest <= nums[i])) {
        newArr.push(nums[i]);
      }
    }
    return Math.max(...newArr);
}

const array = [0, 2, 3, 6, 6, 5]

console.log(getSecondLargest(array))
```