# Find max for an array, 0 if array is empty

Tags: javascript

I need a clean way of finding `max` for an array in JavaScript. Say it is `arrayMax`, then:

```
arrayMax([]) // => 0
arrayMax([1], [2]) // => 2
arrayMax([-1]) // => -1
```

What I've tried:

```
Math.max.apply(null, [1,2,3]) // => 3
```

But it doesn't work for:

```
Math.max.apply(null, []) // => -Infinity
```

Note that it's not an duplication with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values) since I want the empty array to return 0, instead of `-Infinity`

Comment: @Satpal: tried, and updated. Note that Math.max([]) gives u 0 because [] is converted into number 0. You can try Math.max([1,2,3]) and see how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a function that checks the length of the array:

```
function arrayMax(arr) {
    return arr.length ? Math.max.apply(null, arr) : 0;
};
```

Solutions that start with 0 will produce wrong results for arrays with only negative values.

With ES6 support, you can avoid the `apply` method and use the spread operator:

```
function arrayMax(arr) {
    return arr.length ? Math.max(...arr) : 0;
};
```

Comment: If you have fairly large arrays, this will fail. After _500,000_, this throws: `Math.max(...Array(500001).fill().map(_ => Math.random()))` gives `RangeError: too many function arguments`.

Answer (score 4):

check array's length property.

```js
var arrayMax = function(arr) {
  //Check length 
  if (arr.length == 0)
    return 0;

  //Otherwise use take advantage of native API
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
};

console.log(arrayMax([]))
console.log(arrayMax([3,5,1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

This method does not require checking array's length. There may be some other drawbacks though:

```js
function arrayMax( arr )
{
  return arr.reduce(function(prevValue, curValue, curIndex){
    return Math.max( prevValue, curValue );
  }, 0);
}

console.log( arrayMax(["1", "-2"]) );
console.log( arrayMax(["10", "2", ""]) );
console.log( arrayMax([]) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myArray.reduce(function(prev,current){
    return prev===null ? current : Math.max(prev, current);
}, null) || 0
```

or very succinctly with ES6 arrow functions:

```
 myArray.reduce((prev,current) => 
     prev===null ? current : Math.max(prev, current), null) || 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by,

```
function arrayMax(){
 var val = Math.max.apply(null, [].concat.apply([], [...arguments]));
 return val == -Infinity ? 0 : val
}

console.log(arrayMax([1],[22,3,2],[3])); //22
console.log(arrayMax([1],[3])); //3
console.log(arrayMax([1])); //1
console.log(arrayMax([])); //0
```

Comment: What if I had `[-Infinity, -1]`?

Comment: @trincot `-1` would be returned hence it is the maximum value there.

Comment: True, I was too quick. But `[-Infinity]` will give 0.

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this question but need a solution for arrays with only positive numbers:

If you are on ES >= 6 this is astonishingly simple.
You can use the spread operator (mentioned in other answers) and add an additional zero parameter to Math.max. The additional zero kicks in if the given array is empty:

```
Math.max(...[], 0)          // => 0
Math.max(...[22,88,55], 0)  // => 88
```