# JavaScript: min & max values in very big array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, minmax

How can I easily obtain the min and max values from a very big JavaScript Array (e.g 250 thousand numbers)?

I tried to use this method, but it does not work: [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

I'm debugging in VisualStudio where I don't get any error, while in the browser I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Example code:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(-Infinity, arr);
var min = Math.min.apply(Infinity, arr);
```

"arr" is my very big array.

Comment: First, first argument of apply is context. It should be `null` or `this`. Second you can always go back to custom for loop. That is the safest option

Comment: what's the problem with your code? In my chrome is working.

Comment: for me the code also works, what browser are you using ?

Comment: I tried using null, this or Math, and the effect is always the same.

Comment: @PAPP - I think it's worth mentioning what browser you are using so that others can have a chance of replicating your issue.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I used it in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer with the same result. It is important that this code works with smaller arrays (I tried with 65K elements).

Comment: One certainly safe way of doing this job is using `Array.prototype.reduce()`.

Comment: @PAPP this is interesting: might be a performance issue? What you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: @pietro909 I used Visual Studio as a debugger, and I did not have any error message. But now I checked using tools from the browser, and there is an error: "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Comment: so you got it: there is a limit. Turns out that you can't do that.

Comment: I suspect that is using recursion under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

For large arrays of mentioned sizes you can not use `Math.min()` or `Math.max()` safely. I believe this is how it should be done.

```js
var arr = new Array(1000000).fill().map(_=> ~~(Math.random()*10000000)),
findMax = a => a.reduce((res,cur) => res < cur ? cur : res ,-Infinity);
console.log(findMax(arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

It is working fine for me

```
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, array);
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, array);
```

Comment: I tried using null, this or Math, and the effect is always the same. Are you sure you tried to use it on such a large array as I described? Because this code works with smaller tables (I tried with 65K elements).

Comment: I didn't tried with large arrays, let me check once @PAPP

Comment: There is no guarantee when you need to pass arguments in the order of 150-300 K that you won't get stack overflow depending on the browser session. Large arrays can not be done by `Math.min()` or `Math.max()`