# Typescript error "Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'"

Tags: angular, typescript

I get the following error in Typescript:

> Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

I get the max value of array without the below error:

```
analysis_horizon_array_test: number[] = [];

this.analysis_horizon_array_test.push(1)
console.log(Math.max(this.analysis_horizon_array_test));
```

How do I get the max value of an array without throwing an error? It does work though.

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values

Comment: The only reason this "works" is because the array has one element. `Math.max([2, 6])` is `NaN`.

Comment: Tampa, it looks like you have a good answer below. Would you accept it, please? It is customary to respond in some fashion to helpful people here.

Answer (score 12):

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) takes individual numbers, not an array. You can use spread syntax if you're compiling to a supported target, otherwise you have to use `apply`:

```
console.log(Math.max(...this.analysis_horizon_array_test));
```