# How to append the maximum value of an array of text values?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to extract the maximum value from each of the two submenus and append it to `p`.

```js
$('.submenu').each(function(index, element) {
$('#output')
  .append($(".element").map(function() {
      return this.text();
    })
    .get().Math.max();
  );
 });
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='submenu'>
    <span class='element' style=''>1</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>5</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>7</span>
  <p id='output'>

  </p>

</div>
  <div class='submenu'>
    <span class='element' style=''>1</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>3</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>2</span>
  <p id='output'>

  </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Thus, the output should look like:

```
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='submenu'>
    <span class='element' style=''>1</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>5</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>7</span>
  <p id='output'>7</p>

</div>
  <div class='submenu'>
    <span class='element' style=''>1</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>3</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>2</span>
  <p id='output'>3</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the use of multiple elements with the same ID attribute can cause problems you should change one of them

Comment: [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) + [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bugs in your code:

1. Get `.output` within the current context by specifying the [context as an argument](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context).
2. The [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is jQuery method so wrap `this` with jQuery.
3. The usage of [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) is not in a valid format in your code, use it with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass the array of elements as arguments.
4. The `id` should be unique so use `class` instead for the output element and although specify the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) in the selector.

```js
$('.submenu').each(function(index, element) {
  $('.output', this).append(Math.max.apply(Math, $(".element", this).map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='submenu'>
    <span class='element' style=''>1</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>5</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>7</span>
    <p class='output'>

    </p>

  </div>
  <div class='submenu'>
    <span class='element' style=''>1</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>3</span>
    <span class='element' style=''>2</span>
    <p class='output'>

    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was working on almost the same answer, you beat me to it!