# Typescript and filter Boolean

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

Consider following [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20a%3A%20(number%20%7C%20null)%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20null%2C%204%2C%205%2C%206%5D%3B%0D%0Avar%20b%3A%20%7B%20value%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%5B%5D%20%3D%20a.map(x%20%3D%3E%20x%20!%3D%20null%20%26%26%20%7B%20value%3A%20x%20%7D).filter(Boolean)%3B) with `strictNullChecks` turned on:

```
var a: (number | null)[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, null, 4, 5, 6];
var b: { value: number; }[] = a.map(x => x != null && { value: x }).filter(Boolean);
```

It fails to compile due to:

```
Type '(false | { value: number; })[]' is not assignable to type '{ value: number; }[]'.
  Type 'false | { value: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ value: number; }'.
    Type 'false' is not assignable to type '{ value: number; }'.
```

But it is absolutely clear, that `false` will be filtered away by `.filter(Boolean)`.

Same problem with `null`.

Is there a way (except writing `as number[]`) to mark that value doesn't contain `false` or `null`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you really don't want to change the generated JavaScript, and instead prefer to force the TypeScript compiler to recognize that `Boolean` is serving as a guard against `false` values, you can do this:

```
type ExcludesFalse = <T>(x: T | false) => x is T;     
var b: { value: number; }[] = a
  .map(x => x != null && { value: x })
  .filter(Boolean as any as ExcludesFalse);
```

This works because you are asserting that `Boolean` is a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), and because `Array.filter()` is [overloaded](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10027) to return a narrowed array if the callback is a type guard.

The above (`Boolean as any as ExcludesFalse`) is the cleanest code I could come up with that both works and doesn't change the generated JavaScript.  The constant `Boolean` is declared to be an instance of the global `BooleanConstructor` interface, and you can merge an `ExcludesFalse`-like type guard signature into `BooleanConstructor`, but not in a way that allows you to just say `.filter(Boolean)` and have it work.  You can get fancier with the type guard and try to represent guarding against all falsy values ([except `NaN`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15135)) but you don't need that for your example.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: You can even do :

`const ExcludesFalse = Boolean as any as <T>(x: T | false) => x is T;`
`array.filter(ExcludesFalse);`

Comment: `.filter(<T>(n?: T): n is T => Boolean(n))` works on 3.1.6 at least

Answer (score 73):

You can use functions like this

```
function nonNullable<T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> {
  return value !== null && value !== undefined;
}

type Truthy<T> = T extends false | '' | 0 | null | undefined ? never : T; // from lodash

function truthy<T>(value: T): value is Truthy<T> {
    return !!value;
}

[1, 2, 0, null].filter(nonNullable) // number[]
[1, 2, 0, null].filter(truthy) // number[]
```

NonNullable - 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude any non null values like this

```
type ValidValue<T> = Exclude<T, null | undefined | 0 | '' | false>;
const BooleanFilter = <T>(x: T): x is ValidValue<T> => Boolean(x);
var a: (number | null)[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, null, 4, 5, 6, undefined];
const values = Object.values(a).filter(BooleanFilter);
console.log(values)  // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
export function isTruthy<T>(value?: T | undefined | null | false): value is T {
  return !!value
}
```

Then do

```
const arrayWithNoFalsyValues = arrayWithFalsyValues.filter(isTruthy)
```

`arrayWithNoFalsyValues` type will be `T[]` and won't be `(T | null | ...)[]`

Fill free to add more falsy values/types to the type of `value` in `isTruthy(value)`