# TS value still possible undefined after filter

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter, promise, undefined

TS version: `^4.4.3`

I have a function that is as follows

```js
export const settleAll = async <Result = Record<string, any>>(promises: Promise<Result>[]) =>
  ((await Promise.allSettled(promises))
    .map((res) => (res.status === 'fulfilled' ? res.value : null))
    .filter(Boolean) as unknown) as Result[]
```

And I can use it as follows:

```js
const myCoupons: string[] 
const result = (
  await settleAll<Coupon | undefined>(
    myCoupons.map(
      coupon => (await axiosClient.post<Coupon>('/coupons/reserve', {coupon})).data
  )
)
// You would expect TS to consider that the value can't be undefined after this filter, 
// you would expect that
.filter(Boolean)
// or after this one
.filter(r => !!r)
.map((c) => {
  // but nope you need this
  if (!c) return
  // so you can do this
  return filterCoupon<FilteredCoupon>(c)
})
// but it's still considered to be possible to be undefined here
.filter(Boolean)
.filter(r => !!r)

// and after all
// it's still `result: (FilteredCoupon | undefined)[]` here
```

I'm really confused here.
I can even add `.filter(r => typeof r !== 'undefined')` and it will still consider it possibly undefined.

I don't really know what more to type here, but SO won't let me post without more details that are not in code blocks -.-'

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632622/typescript-and-filter-boolean), but it just makes typescript think the signature is `Promise<Coupon | undefined | null>[]` :s

Comment: It says that `promises` is an array of promises that each resolve to `Result`.
And when you use `promise.allSettled` it returns an object with `status` and `value` where `value` is the value returned by each promise.
I don't see how that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I stand corrected