# Getting rid of unknown in TypeScript casting

Tags: typescript, casting, type-conversion, tslint

I wrote the below code.

```
  const incompleteKYCClaims = completedProvidersWithoutStripeAccount.map( async (p) => {
    const provider = await getProviderOrThrow(p.tin)
    const isPreviouslyApproved = previouslyApproved.includes(provider.status)
    if (isPreviouslyApproved) return
    return toProviderRelationshipClaims({tin: p.tin, role: ProviderUserSubRoles.ky, status: 'KYCInDraft'})
  }).filter(claim => !!claim) as unknown as Array<ProviderRelationshipClaims>
```

It maps an array to another array skipping entries where `isPreviouslyApproved` is `true`.

In order for type-checking to pass, I have to convert `Array<ProviderRelationshipClaims | unknown>` to `unknown` then convert that to `Array<ProviderRelationshipClaims>`. This should not be necessary as `filter(claim => !!claim)` will filter-out `undefined`. However, typescript checker does not get this. At least, this is how I interpret this.

How could I get rid of conversion to `unknown`, and/thus to make this code fragment nicer [more elegant]? Any recommendations?

Thank you

Comment: Please make sure that you are providing [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently your code snippet has a lot of things missing

Comment: The filtering will get of rid undefined, but unknown means it could be anything. unknown isn't undefined. We can't tell where the unknown is coming from here.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that we can paste as-is into our own IDEs to have something tangible to work with that doesn't have errors unrelated to your problem.  Right now it's got a lot of undeclared variables and functions, so I'd have to guess their types and work on declaring them myself before I could even begin to test anything, and then other people might make different guesses.  Could you [edit] to give us something common and testable so we're all on the same page?

Comment: By the way, you might use flatMap instead of map then filter.

Comment: @TrevorDixon i don't see what my example has to do with flatMap, nor believe that your advice could apply. my guess is that you did not understand the question. this question is how to deal with typescript type conversions. thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632622/typescript-and-filter-boolean answers your question?

Comment: @IgorShmukler I think I understand. https://www.stefanjudis.com/snippets/filter-and-map-array-values-with-a-flatmap-one-liner/. Helps clarify types at the same time as an added benefit. But in your case where you've got `unknown`, it won't solve the problem entirely. You can't just filter out `unknown`. Whatever function is returning that needs to be changed. There's not enough info in your question to know what to do. "This should not be necessary as filter(claim => !!claim) will filter-out undefined." This is true but irrelevant. You're dealing with `unknown`, not `undefined`.

Comment: @TrevorDixon wish I understood you, but the thought escapes me. Sorry. ;) Max did explain how to solve this.

Comment: Oh another problem! You're using an async function in map, so you must be getting an array of promises, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

Think that adding a return type to the filter will work for you.

If I understand the issue, its basically like this example right?

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, undefined, 4];

const filtered = arr.filter(x=>x!==undefined); //(number | undefined)[] ..
```

but should be number array.

If you do

```
const filtered = arr.filter((x):x is number=>x!==undefined); //number[]
```

then you get number array.

So for your code, if you know the type you can do

```
.filter((claim): claim is ProviderRelationshipClaims => !!claim)
```

assuming `ProviderRelationshipClaims`  is the type other than undefined.

Otherwise I think that you can do this

```
arr.filter(<T extends unknown>(z:T): z is Exclude<T,undefined> => z !== undefined);
```

which I guess should work for most types