# Convincing TypeScript compiler that filtered array contains no nulls

Tags: typescript

I came across an interesting case where the TypeScript compiler (with `strictNullChecks === true`) wouldn't let me pass an array *with nulls filtered out* to a function requiring a number array.

Here is a code sample showing the problem:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
        const values = [1, 2, null, 4].filter(x => x);
        this.printNumberArray(values);
    }

    printNumberArray(values: number[]) {
        console.log(values);
    }
}
```

This causes a red squiggle to appear under `values` with this error:

```
Argument of type '(number | null)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

const values: (number | null)[]
```

The `filter` is guaranteed to eliminate the null values, but apparently the compiler is not able to recognize that.

I'm able to work around this by casting all values in the array to a number, like this:

```
const values = [1, 2, null, 4]
    .filter(x => x)
    .map(x => x as number);
```

But I can't escape the feeling that "there must be a better way".

So that's my question, is there a recommended/best practices way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript filter out nulls from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118692/typescript-filter-out-nulls-from-an-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the fact that `filter` has an overload like this that works with type guards:

```
filter<S extends T>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];
```

So all you need to do is change your code to:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    const isNotNull = <T>(x: T): x is NonNullable<T> => !!x;
    const values = [1, 2, null, 4].filter(isNotNull);
    this.printNumberArray(values);
  }

  printNumberArray(values: number[]) {
    console.log(values);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is possible without conditional types: `const isNotNull = <T>(x: T | null): x is T => !!x;` and I don't really see the rest of it as "bleeding edge".  What are you thinking might fail about this pattern?

Comment: @jcalz Fair enough; I don't really remember how old the type guard feature is. I guess I could `git bisect` to find out the oldest Typescript this works in.

Comment: @jcalz What I was thinking might fail would be things turning into `{}` when doing things like abstracting over type guard function types.

Comment: Oh, and `Array.filter` [will narrow on type guards itself](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.7.2/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1212) since at least TypeScript 2.1.

Comment: @jcalz Ok cool, so i guess the only thing we need here is the type guard.

Comment: Can you provide a definition for `NonNullable<T>` or an `import` statement if it's something already available? I'm getting `Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.`

Comment: @devuxer It should work in `2.8.1` and higher, since it was added with the conditional type work. If you want to use this in an earlier TS, you can use the alternate definition of `isNotNull` @jcalz posted above: `const isNotNull = <T>(x: T | null): x is T => !!x`.

Comment: Ah OK, so what's the advantage of yours vs. jacalz' (given that it's more verbose and more "cutting edge").

Comment: Also, I must confess that I don't fully understand either. The `<T>` is confusing me. Is that a type cast or a generic parameter?

Comment: @devuxer I can't think of any concrete advantages/disadvantages besides backwards compatibility, you can use whichever one appeals to you. I prefer `NonNullable` because it's a builtin. The `<T>` is a function type parameter. In English, `isNotNull`'s type can be read as: for any type `T`, I will take a value `x` of type `T` and determine whether the value is a member of the non-nullable equivalent of `T`.

Comment: Just wanted to add this much simpler (though not generic) solution: `const values = [1, 2, null, 4].filter((x): x is number => !!x);`.

Comment: It's worth noting this will filter out 0, which depending on your use case may be undesirable.