# Using getter & setters with type guard in setter

Tags: javascript, typescript, getter-setter

I would like to add a getter and setter to my class. However the setter is supposed to receive a `querySelector` but the getter returns a new type `pageSections`.

My issue is that the getter and setter must have the same argument/return value, but I want to put the type guard in the setter. `pageSections` is defined in a type definition file and works fine.

```js
// in the code …
this.parent(this.closest('page-sections'))

// in the class
PageSection {
  private _parent: pageSections = undefined

  /**
   * @method setter parent
   * @description set the parent property
   */
  set parent (parent: pageSections) {
    if (this._parent === parent) return
    if (typeof parent.current === undefined) return // this validates it being a pageSections for now
    this._parent = parent
  }

  /**
   * @method getter parent
   * @description get the parent property
   */
  get parent (): pageSections {
    return this._parent
  }
}
```

What am I missing? How should this be done?

Comment: `get/set` must return/accept the same type, this a restriction build into the compiler, no way around it. You can leave `get parent (): pageSections` and have a different property for set, for example `set parent_(parent: querySelector)`. A hack for sure but the only way to do it ..

Comment: *"I would like to add a getter and setter to my class"* -- classes with public properties or getters **and** setters are procedural programming in disguise. Move the code that uses the getter and the setter into the class and you won't need getters and setters any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that and why should it be possible?

You can:

- create another method (setParent(q:querySelector))
- create a converter that elaborates the querySelector and returns a pageSections to set using "set parent"

You can find here an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2521) about it (still discussed from 2015).

Comment: Hmm, okay I am currently using the `setParent` method. It would be nicer to have it all in the setter, but if this is not possible, I guess this is the next best thing.

Comment: Yes @LukasOppermann. As you can read on GitHub is expensive for the TypeScript team and for someone is something that could create problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package,

[@p4ck493/ts-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@p4ck493/ts-is)

there is an example of how it can be used to check arguments,

[@p4ck493/ts-is#-additional](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@p4ck493/ts-is#-additional)

but in your case you need to have a declared class on which the checks will be performed.

**UDP:**

In your example:

```js
import {TypeGuard} from '@p4ck493/ts-type-guard';
import {is, RegisterInIs} from '@p4ck493/ts-is';

// in the code …
this.parent(this.closest('page-sections'))

// in the class
@RegisterInIs()
PageSection {
  private _parent: pageSections = undefined

  /**
   * @method setter parent
   * @description set the parent property
   */
   @TypeGuard([is.PageSection])
  set parent (parent: pageSections) {
    if (this._parent === parent) return
    // if (typeof parent.current === undefined) return // this validates it being a pageSections for now
    this._parent = parent
  }

  /**
   * @method getter parent
   * @description get the parent property
   */
   @TypeGuard({
    result: [is.PageSection]
  })
  get parent (): pageSections {
    return this._parent
  }
}
```

Or if you need it in the case of JavaScript, see the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74675365/19306873

And yes, I am the author of the package, Harrison, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you are the owner of the linked package, you should state this in your answer.