# Filter to remove undefined items is not picked up by TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In the following code, I would like to not have to add `undefined` as a type annotation for filteredDevice. I think that a filteredDevice should never be undefined since I filter away undefined devices.

But if I remove the `undefined` type annotation, TypeScript complains that `Type 'ICouchDBDocument | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ICouchDBDocument'.`

```
devices
.filter((device: ICouchDBDocument | undefined) => Boolean(device)) //should filter away all undefined devices?
.map((filteredDevice: ICouchDBDocument | undefined) => { ... })
```

How can I change my code so that the filter will have an impact on the type annotation?

Comment: Bro just do a simple if statement, if it is undefined, then don't add. Do the if in the filter HO function

Answer (score 33):

The solution is to pass a type-guard function that tells TypeScript that you're filtering out the `undefined` part of the type:

```
devices
.filter((device): device is ICouchDBDocument => Boolean(device)) //filters away all undefined devices!
.map((filteredDevice) => {
    // yay, `filteredDevice` is not undefined here :)
})
```

If you need to do this a lot then you can create a generic utility function that should work with most types:

```
const removeNulls = <S>(value: S | undefined): value is S => value != null;
```

Here are some examples:

```
devices
.filter(removeNulls)
.map((filteredDevice) => {
    // filteredDevice is truthy here
});


// Works with arbitrary types:
let maybeNumbers: (number | undefined)[] = [];

maybeNumbers
    .filter(removeNulls)
    .map((num) => {
        return num * 2;
    });
```

(I didn't use the `Boolean` function in `removeNulls` in case people want to use it with `number` types - otherwise we'd accidentally filter out falsy `0` values too!)

---

Thanks, I'd been wondering the same thing for a while but your question prompted me to finally work it out :)

Looking at TypeScript's `lib.es5.d.ts`, the `Array.filter` function has this type signature (it actually has two in the file, but this is the one that's relevant to your question):

```
/**
 * Returns the elements of an array that meet the condition specified in a callback function.
 * @param callbackfn A function that accepts up to three arguments. The filter method calls the callbackfn function one time for each element in the array.
 * @param thisArg An object to which the this keyword can refer in the callbackfn function. If thisArg is omitted, undefined is used as the this value.
 */
filter<S extends T>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];
```

So, the key to this is the `value is S` return type of callbackfn, which shows that it is a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).