# How to say is not in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```
(string | undefined)[]
```

I want to convert this type to:

```
(string)[]
```

1. I want to do that without type casting.
2. I can't know the given type in advance, what I know is that it's an array of *stuff*.

So I thought I can simply use `array.filter()` for this:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6]
const filteredArray = arr.filter((item) => typeof item !== 'undefined')
console.log(filteredArray) // type of filteredArray (number | undefined)[]
```

Of course it works in JavaScript, but it TypeScript it doesn't.

It infers filteredArray `(number | undefined)[]` even after filtering.

So I remember there was a type guard keyword called `is`, so I did the following:

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined): value is T {
    return value !== undefined;
}
const filteredArray = arr.filter(isDefined)
```

But it keeps inferring it as `(number | undefined)[]`,

so I thought if there was something like `is not`, probably I can say:

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined): value is not undefined {
```

Full code of my solution that did not work:

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined): value is T {
    return value !== undefined;
}
let arr = [1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6]
arr = arr.filter(isDefined)
```

Comment: Doesn't `!!item` do what you want?

Comment: @GuyIncognito, I don't want to do type casting, I can't know the type in advance

Comment: @EmperorEto, do you mean `arr.filter(Boolean)` ?

Comment: I mean `const filteredArray = arr.filter((item) => !!item)`

Comment: @EmperorEto, I tried it it still says `(number | undefined)[]` [look](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gRgDQwEy4DMuArmACYCmAZgJZiXm4CsuAbALoBQoksdAGyiUEjAIJI4AT1TwkAOkHCEAChW1hAWwCUqAHwwoUgA6UQ1GAEJLGyjp7gIIAZXkCQAcxVKR4yVN0AekDDE0oYcxgfUXIJBGkgA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't TypeScript infer type from filtered arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032214/why-cant-typescript-infer-type-from-filtered-arrays) A better duplicate target: [Way to tell TypeScript compiler Array.prototype.filter removes certain types from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43010737)

Comment: @Normal no `typeof`. See my answer. (Sorry I rushed to add it before question was closed :))

Comment: There is no `not` in TS. But you don't need it for this; you could either annotate your inline callback as a type guard with `item is number`, or you can make your type guard function use `T` and `Exclude<T, undefined>`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ3Jlw). Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Seems to work. what am i missing : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgEQKbBmDATAHgBUA+ACgDcBDAGxAwC5EjEAfRcPLHfASiep0MyFM0QBvAFCIZiAE4YoIOUkH1EAQgC8WjmC7ZceANySAvpIgIUURFTlzEugNoBGADSIATJ4DMnzm4jTwBWTwA2AF1JS2tbbBooDAU8AEEHKgBPJzsHADoEpLkyVExDPhigA

Comment: @TusharShahi **excellent point**, this doesn't seem to be a [mre].  @Normal, please [edit] your question to demonstrate what you mean by "it keeps inferring it as `(number | undefined)[]`" and if you can't reproduce it we might need to close this as irreproducible.

Comment: @jcalz, yes you're right. I also found that my code actually works. However, look at [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgEQKbBmDATAHgBUA+ACgDcBDAGxAwC5EjEAfRcPLHfASiep0MyFM0QBvAFCIZiAE4YoIOUkH1EAQgC8WjmC7ZceANySAvpJqLEVOXMS6A2gEYANIgBM7gMzvO3I3cAVncANgBdSVt7XWiAOmwaKAw5MlRMQz5JSSA) Now I know why it does not work. the reason is, if you re-write the original variable, it will not change the type, however, if you create a new variable, it **will** make a correct type. this is weird.

Comment: @Normal that actually makes sense because if you're re-using the original variable it's effectively casting the right-hand of the assignment back to the type of the original which is `(number|undefined)`.

Comment: I think this question is probably unsalvageable because the code in the example works as intended and the actual problem OP has isn't related to any of the code presented.  I'm not sure what to say about "angry mob", but I find it best to assume good faith on the part of everyone involved until it is actually demonstrated otherwise.

Comment: @jcalz, alright I updated the question

Comment: I think you should probably just close or remove this one and then open a new one that has nothing to do with `is not`, since your problem doesn't have anything to do with that and it's just a distraction. You could demonstrate your issue with `let arr1 = [1, 2, undefined, 3]; const arr2 = [4, 5, 6]; arr1 = arr2;` and then ask why `arr1` isn't narrowed from `(number | undefined)[]` to `number[]`.  There are answers to that but it wouldn't have much of anything to do with this question as written.

Comment: @jcalz agreed but some people (clearly not you) are tripping over each other to close vote and downvote without giving the guy a chance to clarify the issue.

Comment: @EmperorEto and some are tripping over themselves to answer regardless of how useless their answer is for a question that needs clarity.

Comment: @jcalz, ok, here's a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78186668/why-is-my-type-guard-on-array-filter-is-not-working

Comment: @VLAZ yes because half the time the placeholder answer is the only way some people can get a word in.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I created a better question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78186668/why-is-my-type-guard-on-array-filter-is-not-working

Comment: @EmperorEto feel free to review the goals of the site. It's supposed for *useful* content. Not provide place for just *any* content even if it doesn't even address the question.

Comment: I've made placeholder answers for my own use before (not to try to jump in ahead of closure, but to keep notes to flesh out into an answer later) but I always delete them immediately. Then I can edit it at my leisure and undelete it when done, and nobody else has to pay attention to it until and unless it's a suitable answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>A good approach to this with reusable code is to create a type guard that can be passed:</s>

```
function isNotUndefined<T>(item: T | undefined): item is T {
  return item !== undefined;
}
```

This will ensure that the type of `T` is properly inferred to be distinct from `undefined`.

You can check it in this [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gRgDQwEy4DMuArmACYCmAZgJZiXm4CsuAbALoBQoksdAGyiUEjAIJI4AT1TwkAOkHCEACloQAciCgBVCjXqMAlD3AQQAyvIEgA5iqUjxkqUZgB6dzChSADpRgQahhHUXIJBGkuTxhYuPiAPQB%20Li5qMmAoWnAYdS1dfToGcgAeABUAPjVhAFsALhgymAAfGDIqIuMG2lrciEaYAG8ueNEoEgQwXN6AQhQ0doNigG4uAF8gA):

You already did this, so why is it not working, well because typescript is smart. Let us look at your code:

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined): value is T {
    return value !== undefined;
}
let arr = [1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6] // Type of arr is (number | undefined)[];
arr = arr.filter(isDefined) // Since it is the same variable and the initial typing is compatible, it is not changed
```

Your origin type when you declare the initial array is `(number | undefined)[]`.
When you perform the filter operation, this typing is still valid, so typescript does not change the array typing.
Therefore, you need to store the result in a new variable in order for a new typing to be infered:

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined): value is T {
    return value !== undefined;
}
let arr = [1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6] // Type is (number | undefined)[]
let arr2 = arr.filter(isDefined) // Type is number[]
```

Comment: This is true but is exactly the code in the question (except for the name of your function) so it doesn't add anything. The question is probably not suitable for SO, unfortunately.

Comment: This is already the code in the question with the name of the function and the parameter changed. https://www.diffchecker.com/yo1JVjZ8/

Comment: yes, but look at [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgEQKbBmDATAHgBUA+ACgDcBDAGxAwC5EjEAfRcPLHfASiep0MyFM0QBvAFCIZiAE4YoIOUkH1EAQgC8WjmC7ZceANySAvpJqLEVOXMS6A2gEYANIgBM7gMzvO3I3cAVncANgBdSVt7XWiAOmwaKAw5MlRMQz5JSSA)

Comment: @Normal the type of the variable is determined when you create it. Because you should always be able to assign *at least* the same things as it had initially.

Comment: @Normal but that is a very different situation and has nothing whatsoever to do with `is not`

Comment: @VLAZ, alright that's the answer.