# Why is my type guard on array.filter is not working?

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```
(string | undefined)[]
```

I want to convert this type to:

```
(string)[]
```

1. I want to do that without type casting.
2. I can't know the given type in advance, what I know is that it's an array of *stuff*.

So I thought I can simply use `array.filter()` for this:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6]
const filteredArray = arr.filter((item) => typeof item !== 'undefined')
console.log(filteredArray) // type of filteredArray (number | undefined)[]
```

Of course it works in JavaScript, but it TypeScript it doesn't.

It infers filteredArray `(number | undefined)[]` even after filtering.

So I thought I can do this by creating a custom type guard function:

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined): value is T {
    return value !== undefined;
}
const filteredArray = arr.filter(isDefined)
```

But it keeps inferring it as `(number | undefined)[]`,

Full code of my solution that did not work:

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined): value is T {
    return value !== undefined;
}
let arr = [1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6]
arr = arr.filter(isDefined)
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgEQKbBmDATAHgBUA+ACgDcBDAGxAwC5EjEAfRcPLHfASiep0MyFM0QBvAFCIZiAE4YoIOUkH1EAQgC8WjmC7ZceANySAvpJqLEVOXMS6A2gEYANIgBM7gMzvO3I3cAVncANgBdSVt7XWiAOmwaKAw5MlRMQz4gA)

Comment: Most of this is unnecessary to be a [mre]. You can demonstrate this much more directly with `let arr = [1, 2, 3, undefined, 4, 5, 6]; arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and then ask why your second thing isn't narrowed. It has nothing whatsoever to do with filtering, and everything to do with narrowing or lack of narrowing upon reassignment of a variable. I tried to make this clear on your other question but I guess I didn't do a proper job. Would you mind [edit]ing this to remove all references to "type guard" and "filter" and just talk about narrowing on reassignment?

Comment: @jcalz, alright, one sec

Comment: You might also find [this library](https://github.com/total-typescript/ts-reset) of some use.

Comment: @Normal forgive me but I'm now confused what the issue is. Are you wanting `arr` to become `number[]` rather than `(number|undefined)[]`? I don't think that's possible - once the variable is first defined its type isn't going to change. Think about it like any other typed language, C#, etc. If you say in C# `var a = 5; var b = (int?)null; b = a;` then `b` is going to remain `int?` even though it was assigned a non-null value. Typed variables don't change their type. That's kind of the point. So what is it you're trying to do exactly that you can't?

Comment: @EmperorEto there is such a thing as [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) in TypeScript but it only works when the variable is of a union type directly.  While `number | undefined` is a union type, `(number | undefined)[]` is not. Non-unions don't get narrowed; there's a longstanding feature request at [ms/TS#16976](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16976) for that. There's a lot of interesting stuff to be said here, once the question is edited to provide a [mre].

Comment: it works if you assign the result of filter to a new array https://tsplay.dev/mAabkm

Comment: @jcalz aah ok I see your point. This must be what he's getting at then. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawBQEMBO+AXImCALYBGa+A2gLoCUiA3ogL4BQoksCiMAM4ARNMBhg0AEwA8AFQB82AG64ANiDQk5iAD6JwUsROmMSqjWgGDEOlp0SPE+NFBD4kFzYgCEAXj8DMCNxSSkAbk4uNVdEAnxEQNoARgAaRAAmdIBmdMNjMPSAVnSANnpOeMS4wgA6cTUoGmwhUVDTSNQMHHjGcKcBwaHhgHoRxCgUIUQpODRBMAByKEQAdzh8TE5OMcQ4KSk1AE8J9EErdc3OLqw8Ooam-BaRAtM+4c4YlfiM6vj6mCNZqtV5SPrXdC3H59IA

Comment: @Normal, please edit the question as I asked. Right now this still reads as a duplicate of the other one and the bot came along and smashed it. If you edit the question as I asked, I'll vote to reopen.