# Argument of type 'Promise<Item | undefined>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Item[]>'

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, async-await, use-state

I'm relatively new to React. I want to make a function that call items data from Firebase using a list of ids.

I use TypeScript, React Native and Hooks.

I try the following code :

```
const FavoritesScreen = () => {
  const [favoritesData, setFavoritesData] = useState<Array<Item>>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    init()
  }, [])

  const init = async () => {
    const data = await getFavorites(sortByTimeStamp)
    setFavoritesData(data)
  }

  // ...
```

Someone recommended me to put the declaration of the init function out of the useEffect hook when using async/await. It is working so far.

getFavorites is declared with async as it needs to await data from Firebase.

Visual Studio underline the word data in setFavorites(data) with the following comment:

```
const data: Promise<Item | undefined>[]
Argument of type 'Promise<Item | undefined>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Item[]>'.
  Type 'Promise<Item | undefined>[]' is not assignable to type 'Item[]'.
    Type 'Promise<Item | undefined>' is missing the following properties from type 'Item': author, authorName, authorTitle, benefits, and 13 more.ts(2345)
```

It is not clear for me if the issue is the promise or the undefined, neither how to fix it.

Here is the full code if it can help:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import colors from '../constants/colors'
import { FirebaseContext, FavoritesContext } from 'src/firebase'
import { Item } from '../types/item'
import { Timestamp } from '@firebase/firestore-types'

type CompareFunction = (a: [string, Timestamp], b: [string, Timestamp]) => number

const FavoritesScreen = () => {
  const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext)
  const { favorites } = useContext(FavoritesContext)
  const [favoritesData, setFavoritesData] = useState<Array<Item>>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    init()
  }, [])

  const init = async () => {
    // call the functions used in useEffect
    const data = await getFavorites(sortByTimeStamp)
    setFavoritesData(data)
  }

  // This function gets Firestore data for one id
  const getItemDataFromId = async (id: string) => {
    try {
      const data: Item = await firebase.db.collection('content').doc(id).get().data()
      return data
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Could not get Firebase data from Id: ${id}. Error message: ${error}`)
    }
  }

  // this function compare the timestamps for use in the Array.prototype.sort() method.
  function sortByTimeStamp(a: [string, Timestamp], b: [string, Timestamp]) {
    let am = 1
    let bm = 1
    try {
      const am = a[1].toMillis()
    } catch {
      return -1
    }
    try {
      const bm = b[1].toMillis()
    } catch {
      return 1
    }
    return am - bm
  }

  // Create an array of items data from the favorites object, sorted ny timestamp
  const getFavorites = async (compareFunction?: CompareFunction) => {
    // Convert the object to a [[key1, value1],[key2,value2],...) array
    const favoritesArray = Object.entries(favorites)
    // sort if needed
    compareFunction && favoritesArray.sort(compareFunction)
    // get the data from firebase
    const items = favoritesArray.map(async ([key, value]) => await getItemDataFromId(key))
    return items
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Work in progress</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

//// Styles ////
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.background,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})

export default FavoritesScreen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue you are likely running into is processing async items within the `map` function. This is returning an array of promises that resolve to `Item` rather than an array of `Item` elements.

An easy fix for this is to wrap this in [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```js
const items = favoritesArray.map(async ([key, value]) => await getItemDataFromId(key));
return Promise.all(items);
```

However, after this, you'll likely run into an issue with the return type being `Array<Item | undefined>` rather than only `Array<Item>`. There are a few ways this could be solved. The `items` value could be casted to `Item[]`, but it's probably preferable to filter out the undefined values. For that, I would recommend looking [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118692/typescript-filter-out-nulls-from-an-array). For example:

```js
items.filter((x): x is Item => x !== undefined);
```

Comment: Thanks. Everything is fine now !

Comment: `items.filter((x): x is Item => x !== undefined);` I didn't now what the `Item` type was supposed to be so instead I checked if item is truthy to make get rid of undefined issue  `items && (await Promise.all(items))`