# Removing undefined from ES6 mapping without Typescript errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

When an object has an id that could be undefined and you want to select all the existing ids from an array of those objects, why does the following produce a Typescript error saying y.id may be undefined?

```
.filter(x => x.id !== undefined).map(y => y.id)
```

Comment: Because `.filter` doesn't change the type of your array. If the type is `Array<{id?: number}>` then filtering also produces an array of type `Array<{id?: number}>`. After all, TS can't properly analyse the logic of your filtering function - you can also do `.filter((x, index) => index % 2 === 1)` and you might still have missing IDs in your dataset.

Comment: What is the type of the object? If it is an union type, you may try using [type predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700791/14431863)

Comment: Makes sense but how are you meant to remove the error then? It's a complex object so it can't be cast to a simple type

Comment: You can probably just do `map(y => y.id!)`

Comment: You could use a type guard for filtering [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMssACYD8AXMiAK4C2ARtMgNzHIwD231tjFlA4BfQoQTcQAZzCkQOOmBoZseANoBdZAF5k6zvnI0AjCIA0hntxoAWAEwXDx5I8ubxkmXKgRpdABtlAWZoLV15RTBOADoYYCDoAAoACzhpAEkyAEpYhjgcJPRdAD5kdBjyXMIYOhAEMGApZDTMsgAeTBKk4EgGGiNKGkwRbJpeiAZSaWRBmgBRAA8EALoyCE7zZDr1+JAIMmQAHwEAgJKRWc5fMDooEGQAInJH+VI+5AAyT-fJysOAIQ6PQ7CB7A5fH4TBj-ZBAvT0M6iIA) however, I'm not exactly sure if that exactly fits your requirement.

Comment: @VLAZ why not? the type of filtered variable will then be just `number []`

Comment: @Evk ah, right...the filtering slipped my mind, sorry

Comment: @Evk, that would not work as there ARE actually undefined values.  I need to get a list of the ids that do exist

Comment: @user3775501 I mean change your existing code in this way, not just do map. So, `.filter(x => x.id !== undefined).map(y => y.id!)`. First you filter out undefined values, then while mapping you assert to the compiler that you are sure `y.id` is defined, via `!` operator.

Comment: @Evk ah ok.  That will work but it's disappointing of Typescript if that's the least tortuous way of removing undefined values!

Comment: Well other languages with type checking are likely to be the same. For example, in C# if you have array of nullable int (`int?`), and do the same as you do in typescript (`.Where(x => x != null).Select(y => y)` then result will also be array of nullable ints. Compiler just cannot reliably check what you are doing inside filter expression, so you have to help him (in case of C# by doing `Select(y => y.Value)`, which is quite close to typescript way of ensuring compiler it cannot be null. YOU know all values are defined, but compiler does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `.filter()` doesn't automatically change the type of the array. If you have `Array<T>` then `.filter()` produces `Array<T>` again. After all, it's not easy to determine *what* are you filtering. Consider this:

```js
const input = [
  { id: 1, name: "Alice" },
  { id: 2, name: "Bob" },
  { name: "Carol" },
  { name: "David" },
];

const result = input.filter(x => x.name.includes("o"));

console.log(result);
```

Would it be right to change the type from `Array<{id?: number, name: string}>` to `Array<{id: number, name: string}>`? No, it wouldn't. The filter clearly still produces items that might not have `id` property. If you don't know the data, then it's even harder to determine what the filtering does and what it's *meant* to do.

However, TypeScript *does* have a typing for

```
interface Array<T> {
    filter<U extends T>(pred: (a: T) => a is U): U[];
}
```

Or a `.filter()` method that transforms from `Array<T>` to `Array<U>`. It accepts [a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) which should tell it that the filtering produces a new type. So, what you can do is use a type guard that will convince the TypeScript compiler that the following the operation, you have IDs. Note that type guards have to return a boolean:

```typescript
interface MyType {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
}

input
  .filter((x): x is MyType & {id: number} => "id" in x)
  .map(y => y.id);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMssACYD8AXMiAK4C2ARtANzG1wMQ0DOYUUAHN2AX0KEEAexD9SIHHTA0M2PAG0AusgC8ydR3ykyNAIwAaTtxoAiAIIAbYEhvJR5w8ZoAmSyC48yDYAQlJMru6e-tZBAMJwUFIOER4kRtGBNgAicABu5CmEmhLSsmDIUBC8dA7KtIwsUFq68opgHAB0MMC10AAUfQAeAJQ0g6S8aFi4KABkyPjkNPTM0KK6AHxBBfLII50McDh96JvI6B3kwyUyvEkQHQ5SQn2V1bXD7EA)

However, this will not catch the cases where the `id` property might be *present* but `null` or `undefined` for example:

```typescript
interface MyType {
  id?: number | null | undefined;
  name: string;
}
```

So, you need to modify the logic to `(x): x is MyType & {id: number} => "id" in x && typeof x.id === "number"`. This starts to get unwieldy and it's not easily reusable if you have a different type like

```typescript
interface Foo {
  id?: number | null | undefined;
  bar: string
}
```

You can generalise the type guard using generics so it will check *any* type that might have an `id`:

```typescript
type IdType<T extends {id?: any}> = T["id"]; //what is the type of the `id` property
type HasId<T> = T & {id: Exclude<IdType<T>, null | undefined>}; // T with a mandatory and non-null `id` property

function hasId<T extends { id?: any }>(item: T): item is HasId<T>{
  return "id" in item        // has `id`
    && item.id !== undefined // isn't `undefined`
    && item.id !== null;     // isn't `null`
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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-p9IL+PPIAuLIvoUvlkiV5roGvWFgNvLoZut5DtkCd7vQCB99OXgBCXh8E5TveGqeFAC5jpiK78uu4DdCK26zP4QA)

This will allow you to filter arrays which contain types with `id` easily:

```typescript
const result: number[] = input
  .filter(hasId)
  .map(y => y.id);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMssACYD8AXMiAK4C2ARtMgD610A2X7ydIMhBigIZANzFacBhBoBnMFFABzSQF9ChMLhQBJMtjwAeTMggAPSIPnJ85asjgh06gHzIAvMkwBtAETk-gC64sgA9OEA7gAWcGCktmAxKDp4yAD2MMjJKAAG5HnIOFAZeFA62rrIABJw8gamHt5mAGR25DQAohYIXHRCxgZGEE0ANJw8fAJCIiBibuphkT7IUcDJTsgMzmTxGVDoToK0GSAAtPRTBWRFJWXQlYQwAghgwGfIcQ1kpuZWEBsdlIlBoziO7gAFBsIAwaJgAJQ0GEMRK1eqNTBuIgkKAQMB0KAgZCBMj+UjElEkanUlbfZA3PJSEitdoogB05GQAEJPN4ZsJRGQIuFEiAAOQJPICuZiJk01mkSAMTnC3neK5cMI0lbAeQSqWapmaQgIM6KCk4OhgGgYEa+YJeZC+KT4EE0ACMExAMjkJIAglxgEhyeoxq73cgAEze300fwAIQyTFD4ZIbp9snjAGE4KUuKmI5m-f4ACJwABuQWQYYjnUmXFjWZJXSEBZraeB9ZlQqbJYAYniyR3CMEtGaQBa8fJuDbOMxoA6naArWApOyRFxIFBId8DAj1zscJCjp4POhVQjJKbzRkuBB2VwMipIdPZ1fCEA)