# How to tell Typescript filtered array of objects contain a key?

Tags: typescript

In the following code:

```
interface Obj {
    requiredKey: string;
    optionalKey?: string;
}

type Arr = Array<Obj>;

const arr: Arr = [
    {
        requiredKey: "a",
        optionalKey: "b",
    },
    {
        requiredKey: "c",
    },
];

const filtered = arr.filter((obj) => obj.optionalKey);
```

How do I tell TS that `filtered` contains objects where `optionalKey` exists? Meaning that the type is now:

```
{
    requiredKey: string;
    optionalKey: string;
}[]
```

Comment: You can use a type-guard with `filter`: [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64426179)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can modify Robby's answer slightly, so that it works without *hard-coding* the `Obj` type inside `filter` and also without accidentally making unrelated properties required.

```
const filtered = arr.filter(
  (obj): obj is typeof obj & { optionalKey: string } => 
    typeof obj.optionalKey === 'string'
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeBYAKGWOSggEcBXYMgEwGkIBPALmQGcwpQBzAbkIlkAewAOYYMJBwANoyYB%20Np24h%20hAL6FCYJqJQBBKFGQBeZEahwmAHgyYAfAIKEEUzsjjG2ls8gDagiT4REIkZFQ0EAzMbABEcHEANEFhIuKS0nKxyHHoyanIGimhxCFpxBHUdPLxCAWlRSUAus6u7mDIMMAykHR%20XlAAdN290AAUhePCWACUbDPYwOzIuvrCMCJYyABkuOkSUrK1HFy8RWYOq3oQG1uYQ2KHWfJmpuYA5Cq8H4SzfEA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) utility type with a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
interface Obj {
    requiredKey: string;
    optionalKey?: string;
}

const arr: Array<Obj> = [
    {
        requiredKey: "a",
        optionalKey: "b",
    },
    {
        requiredKey: "c",
    },
];

const filtered = arr.filter(
    (obj): obj is Required<Obj> => typeof obj.optionalKey === 'string'
);
```