# (string | undefined) array to string array

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

Good afternoon!

I'm working on creating a function in TypeScript that receives a `string | undefined` array that returns another array containing only `string` elements. In other words, a function that matches this signature:

```
functionName(arraySource: (string | undefined)[]): string[]
```

I've tried filtering the array by its type (via functional programming) with a line like:

```
array.filter(x => typeof x === "string")
```

The problem here is the compiler: it says that the previous method returns a `(string | undefined)[]` variable (which cannot be assigned to a `string[]`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript filter out nulls from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118692/typescript-filter-out-nulls-from-an-array). The answer is applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast the result like this:

`array.filter(x => typeof x === "string") as string[]`

I'm not sure that there's a more sophisticated was to convince the compiler to recognized that the logical consequence of the filtering will be to remove `undefined` values.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is perfect and works fine, answer given in question referenced by @kelly with guards seems to work fine too and avoids casting