# How to get the min and max of an array of numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to get the min and max of an array into two variables?
My current method feels lengthy:

```
var mynums = [0,0,0,2,3,4,23,435,343,23,2,34,34,3,34,3,2,1,0,0,0]
var minNum = null;
var maxNum = null;
for(var i = 0; i < mynums.length; i++) {
  if(!minNum) {
    minNum = minNum[i];
    maxNum = maxNum[i];
  } else if (mynums[i] < minNum) {
    minNum = mynums[i];
  } else if (mynums[i] > minNum && mynums[i] > maxNum) {
    maxNum = mynums[i]
  }
}
```

Other posts that appear to 'address' this seem to be old and I feel like there must be a better way in 2017.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `Math.max()` and `Math.min()`

For an array input, you can do

```
var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, mynums);

var minNum = Math.min.apply(null, mynums);
```

Comment: var mynums = [0,0,0,2,3,4,23,435,343,23,2,34,34,3,34,3,2,1,0,0,0]; Math.max(mynums); // that returns a NaN.

Comment: Added a solution for an array.

Comment: Why is it that you have to use apply/null?

Comment: `.apply` passes a this reference and an array of arguments to the method you use it on. When you `.apply(null, mynums)` you pass each value in the array as an argument to the Math.max() function.

Comment: Most elegant in this day and age.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` and find both min and max at the same time.

```js
var mynums = [0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 23, 435, 343, 23, 2, 34, 34, 3, 34, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]

var {min, max} = mynums.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if(i == 0) r.max = e, r.min = e;
  if(e > r.max) r.max = e;
  if(e < r.min) r.min = e;
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(min)
console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) `min` and `max` functions.

```
var mynums = [0,0,0,2,3,4,23,435,343,23,2,34,34,3,34,3,2,1,0,0,0];
var minNum = _.min(mynums); // 0
var maxNum = _.max(maxNum); // 435
```

And take a look at `minBy` and `maxBy` functions which also could be very useful.