# Pin / Fix multiple elements in Vanilla Javascript on scroll

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm a beginner in javascript and i'm trying to build some stuff with es6 spec.

I would like to recreate the pin effects from ScrollMagic and pin different section while i scroll down my page.

So I have this simple html markup with an header a footer and 3 section:

```
<header class="forewords">
 <h1>Some text</h1>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
 <section class="project" id="item1">this is section 1</section>
 <section class="project" id="item2">this is section 2</section>
 <section class="project" id="item3">this is section 3</section>
</div>

<footer class="endings">
 <h1>some text</h1>
</footer>
```

And I've attached some styles to simulate a realistic situation.

Here comes the javascript logic:

Get all the projects:

```
const projects = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.project'));
```

Get all the projects offset from top and all the projects height:

```
let projectsOffsetTop = projects.map(project => project.offsetTop);
let projectsHeight = projects.map(project => project.offsetHeight);
```

Create a function to update the value if somebody resize the window:

```
function updateProjectsOffsetTop() {
  projectsOffsetTop = projects.map(project => project.offsetTop);
  projectsHeight = projects.map(project => project.offsetHeight);
};

window.addEventListener('resize', updateProjectsOffsetTop);
```

finaly pin the element if the scroll is greater than its offset.

```
function pinElement() {

  if (window.scrollY >= projectsOffsetTop[1]) {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = projectsHeight[1] +'px';
    projects[1].classList.add('fixed');
  } else {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
    projects[1].classList.remove('fixed');
  }

};

window.addEventListener('scroll', pinElement);
```

But i cant make it work with all the projects element. Even with for loop. What is the best practice? I want to solve this in Vanilla ES6 if it's possible.

Find attached the complete js fiddle.

Thanks

```js
const projects = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.project'));
    let projectsOffsetTop = projects.map(project => project.offsetTop);
    let projectsHeight = projects.map(project => project.offsetHeight);

    function updateProjectsOffsetTop() {
      projectsOffsetTop = projects.map(project => project.offsetTop);
      projectsHeight = projects.map(project => project.offsetHeight);
    };

    function pinElement() {

      if (window.scrollY >= projectsOffsetTop[1]) {
        document.body.style.paddingTop = projectsHeight[1] +'px';
        projects[1].classList.add('fixed');
      } else {
        document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
        projects[1].classList.remove('fixed');
      }

    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', updateProjectsOffsetTop);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', pinElement);
```

```css
html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      
    }

    *, *::before, *::after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    header, footer {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10%;
      background-color: grey;
      position: relative;
    }

    .project {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      top: 0;
    }

    #item1 {background-color: yellow;}
    #item2 {background-color: blue;}
    #item3 {background-color: red;}


    .fixed {
      position: fixed;
    }
```

```html
<header class="forewords"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum soluta ipsam quaerat cupiditate neque, necessitatibus amet nihil perferendis sunt minus! Exercitationem nulla inventore, aut beatae magnam, totam et minus hic.</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="project" id="item1">this is section 1</section>
    <section class="project" id="item2">this is section 2</section>
    <section class="project" id="item3">this is section 3</section>
  </div>

  <footer class="endings"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae vel, perferendis ullam totam recusandae sed repellendus cum! Molestiae, aut ut sequi eos quidem nam quo est, ad tempora inventore odit.</h1>
  </footer>
```

Comment: on `resize` nothing happens right ?

Comment: on resize works fine. I just want to know how to iterate the last part of code, the one that fix the element, for all the section :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've provided an amazing MCVE to work on, so thank you so much for taking so much effort and time to ask a great question. The good news is that you are *almost* there! Your logic is sound, and everything makes sense. What you are really missing is this:

- The correct placement of the logic to reset the styles (body top padding and removing the `fixed` class)
- Getting the index of the `.project` element that is closest, but more than, the scroll height

What you want to do in your `pinElement()` method is the following:

1. Reset/unfix everything first
2. Get the `projectsOffsetTop` value that is more than scrollY, but the closest to it (so that it will be element that we want to pin)
3. From that, get the index of the `.project` element that this value belongs to
4. If the index is `-1` (i.e. we do not have an element that fits the criteria in point 2), `return` and stop execution.
5. Otherwise, we perform the logic you have in your original method, but substitute `1` with the index we have identified in step 3.

With that in mind, here is your slightly refactored `pinElement()` method:

```
function pinElement() {

  // Reset all styles
  projects.forEach((project) => {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
    project.classList.remove('fixed');
  });

  // Get the index of the project that is closest to top
  const valueClosestToScrollY = Math.max.apply(Math, projectsOffsetTop.filter((offsetTop) => offsetTop <= window.scrollY));
  const idx = projectsOffsetTop.indexOf(valueClosestToScrollY);

  // If index is not found, we don't do anything
  if (idx === -1)
    return;

  // Otherwise, we set the appropriate styles and classes
  if (window.scrollY >= projectsOffsetTop[idx]) {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = `${projectsHeight[idx]}px`;
    projects[idx].classList.add('fixed');
  }

};
```

Fun tip: you can use template literals to do this:

```
document.body.style.paddingTop = `${projectsHeight[idx]}px`;
```

…instead of this:

```
document.body.style.paddingTop = ${projectsHeight[idx] + 'px';
```

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
const projects = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.project'));
let projectsOffsetTop = projects.map(project => project.offsetTop);
let projectsHeight = projects.map(project => project.offsetHeight);

function updateProjectsOffsetTop() {
  projectsOffsetTop = projects.map(project => project.offsetTop);
  projectsHeight = projects.map(project => project.offsetHeight);
};

function pinElement() {

  // Reset all styles
  projects.forEach((project) => {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
    project.classList.remove('fixed');
  });

  // Get the index of the project that is closest to top
  const valueClosestToScrollY = Math.max.apply(Math, projectsOffsetTop.filter((offsetTop) => offsetTop <= window.scrollY));
  const idx = projectsOffsetTop.indexOf(valueClosestToScrollY);
  
  // If index is not found, we don't do anything
  if (idx === -1)
    return;

  // Otherwise, we set the appropriate styles and classes
  if (window.scrollY >= projectsOffsetTop[idx]) {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = `${projectsHeight[idx]}px`;
    projects[idx].classList.add('fixed');
  }

};

window.addEventListener('resize', updateProjectsOffsetTop);
window.addEventListener('scroll', pinElement);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.project {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: red;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<header class="forewords">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum soluta ipsam quaerat cupiditate neque, necessitatibus amet nihil perferendis sunt minus! Exercitationem nulla inventore, aut beatae magnam, totam et minus hic.</h1>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="project" id="item1">this is section 1</section>
  <section class="project" id="item2">this is section 2</section>
  <section class="project" id="item3">this is section 3</section>
</div>

<footer class="endings">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae vel, perferendis ullam totam recusandae sed repellendus cum! Molestiae, aut ut sequi eos quidem nam quo est, ad tempora inventore odit.</h1>
</footer>
```

---

On a side note, for performance reasons, you might want to look into throttling/debouncing your scroll event, so that `pinElement()` is not called excessively.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution!
I need to study that `Math.max` thing but everything else is perfectly clear.

I've tryed to add debounce but the amount of seconds needed to perform well is not that different from the normal refresh rate i think (with 10 milliseconds still getting some jumping :D )

I din't know about throttling. Maybe it's a better solution.

Comment: @mdash Ah, the `Math.max.apply` part is simply getting a max value out of an array of numbers :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript You can also use the object spread in ES6 if you want to.

Comment: I've made some test and some issue still remain. For example if I resize the windows while I've already some element fixed, I lose the header and everything broke. Furthermore, maybe the thing that i remove the class as the first operation of the function and than put it back everytime I scroll is the main issue in performance matter. Maybe I could flag the fixed item and remove the flag after the second one got the fixed class?

Comment: @mdash You probably have to re-run the `pinElement()` method on resize, too. That should fix it.