# Return Largest Number in an Negative Array. [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Guys i'm working through a program to find the largest Number in an negative array.What would be the best algorithm for this.
ex:
`[-72, -3, -17, -10]`

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: please show *the not so best* algorithm first.

Comment: it's not different from the case where all the numbers are positive. what problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Please explain "largest negative number"? Do you mean `-3` or `-72`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the min/max element of an Array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Math.max` method and `spread` syntax.

```js
array = [-72, -3, -17, -10]
console.log(Math.max(...array));
```

Comment: In my mind the term "largest negative number" is ambiguous... I don't know if the OP meant `-3` or `-72`. (Not that it changes your code much)

Comment: If we wants `-72` then use `Math.min`

Comment: (See... it didn't change your code much)

Comment: Thanks man. I got my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [-72, -3, -17, -10];
var lg = array[0];
var sm = array[0];
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > lg) {
        lg = array[i];
    }  else if(array[i] < sm) {
        sm = array[i];
    }
}
console.log('largest No :' + lg);
console.log('smallest No :' + sm);
```