# Explain: Min/Max array with infinity

Tags: javascript, arrays, max, min, infinity

I was looking into how to find the min and max value in an array (without using Math) and I came across [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript) in a forum:

```js
var array = [4, 2, 3, 4]
var min = arrayMin(array);
out.innerHTML = min;

function arrayMin(arr) {
  var len = arr.length, min = Infinity;
  while (len--) {
    if (arr[len] < min) {
      min = arr[len];
    }
  }
  return min;
};
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

I can't really wrap my head around it and understand it fully, especially the infinity part. 
Could someone be so nice and explain it as simple as possible?

Comment: except from infinity part what did you not understand

Comment: The variable `min` keeps track of the smallest value seen so far. When a value from the array is smaller than that, it becomes the new minimum.

Comment: It is mostly the infinity part to be honest. @ashishsingh

Comment: everything seems as expected except `out.innerHTML = min;` line

Comment: The value `Infinity` is bigger than any other number. By starting out with that as the smallest value, the actual numbers in the array will all be tested. Imagine if it started out with `min = 100;` instead. Do you see why that would not work in some cases?

Comment: @Karen hope the answers clear it up , if not you can comment. I will help

Comment: I've got it now, thank you all!

Comment: a nice workaround is to use the first element and run the loop from index one.

Answer (score 3):

The logic seems to be fine. The code you have added gives minimum value. min is initialised to Infinity and min is updated as you traverse through array.

Lets take a look at what happens for first array element.

```
4 < Infinity //index = 0 min becomes 4
2 < 4 //index = 1 min becomes 2
```

and so on the code will output minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

Infinity is a property of the global object, or in other words, a variable in global scope.

The initial value of Infinity is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY. The value Infinity (positive infinity) is greater than any other number. Mathematically, this value behaves the same as infinity; for example, any positive number multiplied by Infinity equals Infinity, and any number divided by Infinity equals 0.

So, what the above function is doing is creating a temporary variable called `min` that keeps track of the smallest number. When the first comparison is made, it will overwrite the value of `min` every time since `Infinity` is higher than any other number. Then, it continues to iterate through the array making the same evaluation until it exits.

Here is an inline snippet demonstrating how this works:

```js
var array = [4, 2, 3, 4]
var min = arrayMin(array);

function arrayMin(arr) {
  var len = arr.length, min = Infinity;
  while (len--) {
    console.log(min);
    if (arr[len] < min) {
      min = arr[len];
    }
  }
  return min;
};
```

[You can read more about `Infinity` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).